# No module named _graphviz

Tags: python, import, graphviz, importerror, pygraphviz

I installed graphviz and pygraphviz, when I open a cmd and type

```
python
import _graphviz
```

_graphviz can be imported, but when I run a C++ program which will invoke a .py file, there is a line in this .py file which is

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
```

Then it will not be able to import _graphviz, it shows the following info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\project\graph\analysis\x64\Debug\gengraph.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygraphviz as pgv
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\__init__.py", lin
e 54, in <module>
    from agraph import AGraph, Node, Edge, Attribute, ItemAttribute
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line
20, in <module>
    import graphviz as gv
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\graphviz.py", lin
e 7, in <module>
    import _graphviz
ImportError: No module named _graphviz
```

Can you help me, any advice is welcome, thank you!

Comment: I fixed this by installing `python-pygraphviz`

Answer (score 1):

What system are you using? I spent a good 4 hours trying to figure it out on Windows but ended up migrating my project to Ubuntu.
From what I've learned, it's caused by the program not finding the pygraphviz file. It searches in this sequence on Windows: 1,register; 2,PATH; 3,folders. Some methods availables:

**Find the block in setup.py for register and skip it.**

**Rename folder of pygraphviz installation(remove blanks) and move it to a path without blanks**

In Ubuntu, you could simply "sudo easy-install pygraphviz" which worked for me.

Comment: The syntax is `sudo easy_install pygraphviz` but yes this also worked for me. Actually I was just about to give up as pip and git installs just kept failing.

Answer (score -1):

I got this going with AMD64 like this:

#### Win 7 AMD64

- Install [MSFT C++ compiler](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe).
- Install [Anaconda for Win AMD64, Python3](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64.exe).
- Install [graphviz for Win](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php).
- Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to your PATH environment variable.
- Download [pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz).
- Create a Conda environment with Python version 3.4: `conda create --name digraphs python=3.4 anaconda`.
- Enter the environment: `activate digraphs`.
- Install pygraphviz using pip3: `pip install pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`.
- Run example: `python3 ./gviz_simple.py`.
- Exit the environment: `deactivate`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362845/714413