# Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda, pygraphviz

I am trying to install pygraphviz on Windows 10. There are many solutions to this problem online, but none have yet worked for me. The precise problem I'm having is with this via jupyter notebook-->

```
[1] import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

[2]G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1,level=1)
G.add_node(2,level=2)
G.add_node(3,level=2)
G.add_node(4,level=3)

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(2,4)

nx.draw(G, pos=graphviz_layout(G), node_size=1600, cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
    node_color=range(len(G)),
    prog='dot')
plt.show()
```

I get the following errors after [2]:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py 
in 
pygraphviz_layout(G, prog, root, args)
    254     try:
--> 255         import pygraphviz
    256     except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygraphviz'
```

and

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-86a15892f0f0> in <module>()
  9 G.add_edge(2,4)
 10 
---> 11 nx.draw(G, pos=graphviz_layout(G), node_size=1600, cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
 12         node_color=range(len(G)),
 13         prog='dot')

C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py in graphviz_layout(G, prog, root, args)
226 
227     """
--> 228     return pygraphviz_layout(G,prog=prog,root=root,args=args)
229 
230 def pygraphviz_layout(G,prog='neato',root=None, args=''):

C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py in pygraphviz_layout(G, prog, root, args)
256     except ImportError:
257         raise ImportError('requires pygraphviz ',
--> 258                           'http://pygraphviz.github.io/')
259     if root is not None:
260         args+="-Groot=%s"%root

ImportError: ('requires pygraphviz ', 'http://pygraphviz.github.io/')
```

**Here's what I've tried to resolve this**

(1) Regular pip install: "pip install pygraphviz" This is the error I get at the end. *EDIT* I get the same error even if I run cmd as admin.

```
Command "C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\name~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-
n81lykqs\\pygraphviz\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\name~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
b3jz1lk5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\name~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
build-n81lykqs\pygraphviz\
```

(2) Downloading and installing graphviz-2.38.msi, and then downloading both the 64-bit versions of the wheel. This is the result.

```
C:\Users\name\Anaconda3>pip install pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-
win_amd64.whl
pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this 
platform.

C:\Users\name\Anaconda3>pip install pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp27-none-
win_amd64.whl
pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this 
platform.
```

**What I would like to try, but am not sure how to do properly:**

Edit setup.py. I have read a lot about people finding solutions in changing the paths, but I'm not really sure how to do this. This method looks very complex.

Thank you for any help/insight!

Comment: @Jason: What's your *Python* version?

Comment: @CristiFati 3.6, I'm upgrading from 2.7. I have pygraphviz on 2.7 and it works fine.

Comment: @jason: But according to your details it searches for *pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win\_amd64.whl*. Why is that? What command do you use to install *pygraphviz*?

Comment: @CristiFati. `Pip install pygraphviz` doesn't work for me on both 2.7 and 3.6. I was able to install 2.7 by downloading the cp27 whl file. So i'm looking for the cp34 file for python 3.

Comment: @jason: And are yo also on *Anaconda*, or a simple *Python* installation, or a *VEnv*?

Comment: simple Python... on WIndows 10.

Comment: I think it's because I'm trying to install the 64 bit version on 3.6, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 19):

Updated the *repo*: **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PyGraphviz/v1.5](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyGraphviz/v1.5)**:

- Using official *Graphviz 2.42.2* sources
- ***.whl*s (*win_amd64*, *win32*) for currently supported *Python* versions**
- Newer versions might be added (check one level up)

For *Python 2.7*, they are already built: [[UCI.LFD]: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages - PyGraphviz, an interface to the Graphviz graph layout and visualization package.](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz).

**Notes**:

- In some (I guess, most of the) cases, a ***Graphviz* installation will be required on the system where *PyGraphviz* runs on**, because *PyGraphviz* uses some of *Graphviz*'s tools (executables). They can be downloaded, or built (they don't have to match *PyGraphviz* architecture (*032bit* (*PC032*), *064bit* (*PC064*)), as they are invoked). 
  Update: **I also added *Graphviz 2.42.2* build** (*PC032* - as it works on both *PC064* and *PC032* *Win*) **in the above repository**

  - Check it for newer software versions
- Also, a bug (present in previous versions) was fixed. Check [[SO]: pygraphviz 1.5 default edge no arrow? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198637/4788546) for more details

Anyone who wants to know more details about the build process, **read on**!

---

### 1. Intro

Almost 2 years later, and the problem (well, not exactly as in the question) still persists.

I want to start by emphasizing the difference between the 2 packages:

- [[PyPI]: **py**graphviz - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/pygraphviz/#files): the one in question
- [[PyPI]: graphviz - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/#files): (a simpler) one with a similar name

In *Anaconda* environment, [[SO]: Installing PyGraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@TomHanks's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53137438/4788546) **works perfectly**.

*PyGraphwiz* only has available for download an archive (*.zip*, in this case) file, meaning that it contains (*C* / *C++*) sources.

A couple of words about packages (*.whl*s) whose names contain things like ***cp34-none-win_amd64*** (check [[SO]: What does version name 'cp27' or 'cp35' mean in Python? (@WayneWerner's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37028661/4788546) for details):

- They contain binaries (*.so* or *.pyd* (*.dll*)), which are **linked against a specific *Python* library**

  - They are meant to work only with that *Python* version (so *34* is **not** meant to work with *Python **3.6***)
  - Even is one somehow "outsmarts" *PIP* and manages to install such a package (it's not that hard, actually), it will fail at import time, or worse, it has a high probability of crashing *Python*

Now, many packages have prebuilt binaries for most common *Python* versions running on various *OS*es (e.g. [[PyPI]: mysql-connector-python - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/#files)), but just as many don't, and those only contain sources. Unfortunately, *PyGraphviz* is in the 2<sup>nd</sup> category. For the latter ones, `pip install` will:

- Download the sources
- Build the sources locally

  - A *C* (*C++*) compiler **is required**, typically:

    - *GCC* on *Nix*
    - *VStudio* on *Win*
  - They might have other dependencies
- Install the built artefacts (binaries and *.py(c)* files)

As a side note: **`pip -v ...` enables *verbose* mode for the current command, which comes in extremely handy when experiencing install errors**.

Back to our problem: *Python 3.6* needs *VStudio **2015*** ([[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)).
This is a very vast topic, I covered some parts in:

- [[SO]: Simstring (python) installation in windows (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48794384/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469099/4788546)

**You should check them before proceeding and also keep them open, as you will definitely need them in the next steps**.

I have *VStudio 2015 Community* (among many other versions) installed, you should install it too, it's free ([[MS.VStudio]: Still want an older version?](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads)).

*PyGraphviz* depends on [[Graphviz]: Graph Visualization Software](https://www.graphviz.org). So, at build time it will need (parts of) *Graphviz* (which also has other dependencies of its own) to be already built. Unfortunately, I couldn't find prebuilt binaries (there is [[Graphviz]: Windows Packages - graphviz-2.38.zip](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/windows/graphviz-2.38.zip), but that's not helping), so it will have to be built manually.

Before going further:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import pygraphviz"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygraphviz'
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811]> dir /b
> other
> src
> ```

This is my ***top dir***, any sources are downloaded in the *src* *dir*, binaries will be placed in the *bin* *dir*.

### 2. Build *Graphviz*

Before starting, I want to mention that I heavily rely on [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) (you don't have to, there are also other variants (*MSYS2*)), and some of my tools are installed there, so I'll be alternating between *Cygwin* and *Cmd* terminals (which might be confusing).

[[Graphviz]: Graphviz Build Instructions for Windows](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/winbuild.html) states:

> For building on Windows:
>
> **(Graphviz versions ≥ 2.41)**
>
> First, in the root of the repository, perform git submodule update --init. This will download all submodules, which are mostly the dependencies for the Windows build. Next, add the windows\dependencies\graphviz-build-utilities directory to your PATH (and restart Visual Studio or the prompt with which you execute msbuild after that). This folder contains the tools Bison, Flex and SED (and future additions) with versions that are tested. If all went right, the dependencies are now set up and you can build Graphviz.

First, we need to download everything:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045093811/src/graphviz]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> git clone https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz.git .
> Cloning into '.'...
> remote: Enumerating objects: 71728, done.
> remote: Counting objects: 100% (71728/71728), done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19331/19331), done.
> remote: Total 71728 (delta 52200), reused 71681 (delta 52157)
> Receiving objects: 100% (71728/71728), 163.79 MiB | 480.00 KiB/s, done.
> Resolving deltas: 100% (52200/52200), done.
> Checking out files: 100% (3870/3870), done.
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> git submodule update --init
> Submodule 'dependencies/criterion' (https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion.git) registered for path 'dependencies/criterion'
> Submodule 'windows/dependencies/graphviz-build-utilities' (https://github.com/ErwinJanssen/graphviz-build-utilities.git) registered for path 'windows/dependencies/graphviz-build-utilities'
> Submodule 'windows/dependencies/libraries' (https://github.com/ErwinJanssen/graphviz-windows-dependencies.git) registered for path 'windows/dependencies/libraries'
> Cloning into '/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045093811/src/graphviz/dependencies/criterion'...
> Cloning into '/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045093811/src/graphviz/windows/dependencies/graphviz-build-utilities'...
> Cloning into '/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045093811/src/graphviz/windows/dependencies/libraries'...
> Submodule path 'dependencies/criterion': checked out '301d143ea42c024f22b673b69c72a4cb3c8d151f'
> Submodule path 'windows/dependencies/graphviz-build-utilities': checked out '050fff84ce195e0740878748760fd801eeb07b23'
> Submodule path 'windows/dependencies/libraries': checked out '141d3a21be904fa8dc2ae3ed01d36684db07a35d'
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> git show head
> commit 89292b5945933b1501293c04894ed9cf886241be (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
> Merge: 429d43615 97811bd35
> Author: Stephen C North <scnorth@gmail.com>
> Date:   Mon Feb 4 08:09:40 2019 -0500
>
>     Merge branch 'wasbridge/graphviz-master' into HEAD
>
> [064bit prompt]> git status
> On branch master
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
> ```

You'll end up with a *dir* that contains *~320 MiB* of stuff. The *dir* contains a *graphviz.sln* file, which is a *VStudio (2015)* solution file which contains ***63*** projects.

Looking at the *Anaconda* or *Python 2.7* ***PyGraphviz*** (built) package, it only depends on ***cgraph.dll***, which in turn depends on ***cdt.dll***, so only the 2 projects are relevant to us. Note that these 2 projects might not need all the *Git* submodules (so the *dir* might be trimmed down), but I didn't investigate further.

Unfortunately, the projects are only configured for *032bit* (*Win32* platform (*pc032*)). The *064bit* one must be **manually added** (I did it from *VStudio IDE* - and also described the process in one of my answers that I referenced). After saving the projects, they will be shown as modified by *Git*:

> ```bash
> [064bit prompt]> git status
> On branch master
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
>
> Changes not staged for commit:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
>   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
>   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
>
>         modified:   lib/cdt/cdt.vcxproj
>         modified:   lib/cgraph/cgraph.vcxproj
>         modified:   windows/dependencies/graphviz-build-utilities (modified content)
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
> ```

The 3<sup>rd</sup> item is because I needed to reset some security permissions on 2 executables (used when building *cgraph*):

- *bison.exe*
- *flex.exe*

which were not set properly (most likely, because of *Cygwin*).

You can build the 2 projects from *IDE*, but I chose command line ([[MS.Docs]: MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017)) since I find it more flexible:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> [prompt]> set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\src\graphviz\windows\dependencies\graphviz-build-utilities
>
> [prompt]> msbuild src\graphviz\lib\cdt\cdt.vcxproj /t:Rebuild /p:Platform=x64;Configuration=Release;SolutionDir=%CD%\src\graphviz\;OutDir=%CD%\bin\Win\dynamic\064\UCRTv140\md\Release\graphviz\ >build_cdt_064.txt 2>&1
>
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> bin
> build_cdt.txt
> other
> src
>
> [prompt]> msbuild src\graphviz\lib\cgraph\cgraph.vcxproj /t:Rebuild /p:Platform=x64;Configuration=Release;SolutionDir=%CD%\src\graphviz\;OutDir=%CD%\bin\Win\dynamic\064\UCRTv140\md\Release\graphviz\ >build_cgraph_064.txt 2>&1
>
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> [prompt]> dir /b "bin\Win\dynamic\064\UCRTv140\md\Release\graphviz"
> cdt.dll
> cdt.dll.lastcodeanalysissucceeded
> cdt.exp
> cdt.lib
> cgraph.dll
> cgraph.dll.lastcodeanalysissucceeded
> cgraph.exp
> cgraph.lib
> ```

So, we have everything needed (2 *.lib* and 2 *.dll* files) in order to go on.

### 3. Build *PyGraphviz*

*PyGraphviz* sources are (downloaded from [[GitHub]: pygraphviz/pygraphviz - (pygraphviz-1.5) pygraphviz-pygraphviz-1.5.zip](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/archive/pygraphviz-1.5.zip) and) unpacked in *src/pygraphviz/pygraphviz-pygraphviz-1.5*.

One more adjustment is needed to *Graphviz* (probably it's done as part of another project - an *install* step): preparing the header files:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> mkdir include\graphviz
>
> [prompt]> copy src\graphviz\lib\cdt\cdt.h include\graphviz
>         1 file(s) copied.
>
> [prompt]> copy src\graphviz\lib\cgraph\cgraph.h include\graphviz
>         1 file(s) copied.
> ```

Unfortunately, *PyGraphviz* does **not** build *OOTB*, because of [[GitHub]: pygraphviz/pygraphviz - Python 3 support](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/16). To fix that, [[GitHub]: eendebakpt/pygraphviz - Workaround for PyIOBase_Type for Python2 on win](https://github.com/eendebakpt/pygraphviz/commit/b85d12ac22d39063f7dbcc396e825c563431e352) must be applied. I adapted it to work with the current sources (as it doesn't work *OOTB*, as well :X( ) **for *graphviz_wrap.cpp* only**:

*pygraphviz-1.5-all-pyiobase_b85d12ac22d39063f7dbcc396e825c563431e352.patch*:

```
--- pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c.orig 2018-09-10 16:07:12.000000000 +0300
+++ pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c  2019-02-26 18:05:20.281741400 +0200
@@ -2988,7 +2988,18 @@
 
 
 #if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
-extern PyTypeObject PyIOBase_Type;
+static PyObject *PyIOBase_TypeObj;
+
+static int init_file_emulator(void)
+{
+  PyObject *io = PyImport_ImportModule("_io");
+  if (io == NULL)
+    return -1;
+  PyIOBase_TypeObj = PyObject_GetAttrString(io, "_IOBase");
+  if (PyIOBase_TypeObj == NULL)
+    return -1;
+  return 0;
+}
 #endif
 
 
@@ -3449,7 +3460,7 @@
   {
 #if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000 || defined(PYPY_VERSION)
 #if !defined(PYPY_VERSION)
-    if (!PyObject_IsInstance(obj0, (PyObject *)&PyIOBase_Type)) {
+    if (!PyObject_IsInstance(obj0, PyIOBase_TypeObj)) {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "not a file handle");
       return NULL;
     }
@@ -3523,7 +3534,7 @@
   {
 #if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000 || defined(PYPY_VERSION)
 #if !defined(PYPY_VERSION)
-    if (!PyObject_IsInstance(obj1, (PyObject *)&PyIOBase_Type)) {
+    if (!PyObject_IsInstance(obj1, PyIOBase_TypeObj)) {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "not a file handle");
       return NULL;
     }
@@ -6051,6 +6062,12 @@
   
   SWIG_InstallConstants(d,swig_const_table);
   
+#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
+  if (init_file_emulator() < 0) {
+    return NULL;
+  }
+#endif
+
   PyDict_SetItemString(md,(char*)"cvar", SWIG_globals());
   SWIG_addvarlink(SWIG_globals(),(char*)"Agdirected",Swig_var_Agdirected_get, Swig_var_Agdirected_set);
   SWIG_addvarlink(SWIG_globals(),(char*)"Agstrictdirected",Swig_var_Agstrictdirected_get, Swig_var_Agstrictdirected_set);
```

That is a *diff* (*patch*). See [[SO]: Run/Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *UTRunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out).

> ```bat
> [prompt]> :: Restore the original prompt as cwd is important
> [prompt]> exit
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811]> set _TOP_DIR=%CD%
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811]> pushd src\pygraphviz\pygraphviz-pygraphviz-1.5
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811\src\pygraphviz\pygraphviz-pygraphviz-1.5]> pushd pygraphviz && "c:\Install\x64\Cygwin\Cygwin\AllVers\bin\patch.exe" -p 1 -buNi ..\pygraphviz-1.5-all-pyiobase_b85d12ac22d39063f7dbcc396e825c563431e352.patch && popd
> patching file graphviz_wrap.c
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811\src\pygraphviz\pygraphviz-pygraphviz-1.5]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811\src\pygraphviz\pygraphviz-pygraphviz-1.5]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" setup.py install --include-path=%_TOP_DIR%\include --library-path=%_TOP_DIR%\bin\Win\dynamic\064\UCRTv140\md\Release\graphviz >%_TOP_DIR%\install_pygraphviz_064.txt 2>&1
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811\src\pygraphviz\pygraphviz-pygraphviz-1.5]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811\src\pygraphviz\pygraphviz-pygraphviz-1.5]> popd
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811]> set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\bin\Win\dynamic\064\UCRTv140\md\Release\graphviz
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q045093811]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import pygraphviz;print(dir(pygraphviz), \"\n\", pygraphviz.graphviz._graphviz)"
> ['AGraph', 'Attribute', 'DotError', 'Edge', 'ItemAttribute', 'Node', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__revision__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'absolute_import', 'agraph', 'division', 'graphviz', 'print_function', 'release', 'test', 'tests', 'version']
>  <module '_graphviz' (e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\_graphviz.cp36-win_amd64.pyd)>
> ```

As seen, the module was successfully imported.

As a remark, the 2 *.dll* dependencies (from previous section) must be available when the module is imported, so their *dir* is added to *%PATH%*.
Of course this is only a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*), this shouldn't happen every time one has to work with the package.

I don't know (yet) how to instruct *setup.py* to also copy them in the package build / install *dir*, so as an alternative (also workaround) one has to manually copy them in *PyGraphviz* install *dir* (**next to *_graphviz.cp36-win_amd64.pyd***, which is (in my case): *"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz"*).

### 4. Shortcut

Since the whole process is complex and requires lots of manual interventions and hacks, I've managed to build (with minor *setup.py* modifications) the (*.whl*) package.

I am not aware of a simple way to make it publicly available, so (although maybe it's not the best practice,) I uploaded it at **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PyGraphviz/v1.5/pygraphviz-1.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyGraphviz/v1.5/pygraphviz-1.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl)**.

**Notes**:

- The following is **regarding *PyGraphviz*, but it can be generalized and applied to any (*.whl*) package**
- Also, **the *GitHub* repository will be used as an example, but (again) it can apply to (*.whl*s in) any repository, including [[PyPI]: The Python Package Index](https://pypi.org)** (I'm not using the *PyGraphviz* one as it has no binaries, but for example [[PyPI]: numpy 1.17.0 - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.17.0/#files))

You can download it **locally** (*e.g.* in ***C:\Path\to\downloaded***), then install it like (this is one way, check [[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546) for alternatives):

> ```
> "C:\Path\to\Python-3.6-amd64\python.exe" -m pip install "C:\Path\to\downloaded\pygraphviz-1.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
> ```

The above *.whl* is located next to several others. Those are for different *Python* versions (and that happens when the *.whl* contains *.dll*s (*.pyd*s) or *.so*s (on *Nix*) that link to a specific *Python* library). To match your *Python* version search the *.whl* name for ***cp**${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}*. In the current situation, it's *cp**36*** corresponding to *Python **3.6***, but the same principle applies for other *Python* versions (*cp37*, *cp38*, *cp39*, *cp310*, *cp311*, ...). Check [[SO]: What does version name 'cp27' or 'cp35' mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023557/4788546) for more details.
Same thing for the architecture (*win_amd64* / *win32* (*x86_64* / *i686* on *Nix*)).

**Note**: **It works for *Anaconda* environments as well!**

Comment: Hey Cristi, can you take a look at this question? It relates to your wheel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55196206/pygraphviz-1-5-default-edge-no-arrow

Comment: @jason: Note that I've only built it, but never used it (in order to work with graphs), but I'll take a look.

Comment: yeah, it's weird, because it is so basic. I looked on pygraphviz github and didn't see anybody complain, so I'm assuming it's the wheel somehow.

Comment: Thankyou [+] I've gone around this particular circle countless times at different client's sites, each with different parts of the toolchain locked down one way or another. This is one of the clearest and most complete descriptions of the end-to-end process I've come across.

Answer (score 11):

The most voted answers seemed to be installing graphviz, rather than pygraphviz.

If you are using a conda environment, you may try using this channel:

`conda install graphviz pygraphviz -c alubbock`

I tried it out with `networkx 2.1`, it worked fine.

Comment: For me, it threw following error
`ImportError: ('requires pygraphviz ', 'http://pygraphviz.github.io/')`

Comment: @TomHanks: Nice catch! Check my answer though, for a more general resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

#### Win 7 AMD64

- Install [MSFT C++ compiler](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe).
- Install [Anaconda for Win AMD64, Python3](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64.exe).
- Install [graphviz for Win](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php).
- Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to your PATH environment variable.
- Download [pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz).
- Create a Conda environment with Python version 3.4: `conda create --name digraphs python=3.4 anaconda`.
- Enter the environment: `activate digraphs`.
- Install pygraphviz using pip: `pip install pygraphviz-1.3.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`.
- Run example: `python ./gviz_simple.py`.
- Exit the environment: `deactivate`

I put some stuff up on github about it. It's messy, use at your own risk:
https://github.com/darkhipo/Easy-Digraph-Draw

Comment: I wonder why was this downvoted, as opposed to @dot-nix's one (which wasn't, although it should).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it on Windows 10 64-bits and Python 3.6.

**Steps:**

1. Download [Graphviz for windows](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html) from the graphiviz site.
2. Add the Graphviz bin path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` in your Windows path.
3. **Close and reopen your terminals so the path changes is recognized.**
4. Download the [graphviz python 3.6 wheel](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/#files).
5. Install the graphviz wheel.

   `pip install graphviz-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
6. Done!

Comment: I think you and adurbin are asking/answering about different packages.  A case of two similarly named libraries; `pygraphviz` seems to be the one in question, while your solution addresses the package `graphviz` and as such is irrelevant to this question.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353199/graphviz-vs-pygraphviz

Comment: This answer is **INCORRECT** (starting with step ***#4.***). -1. It should be removed altogether.