# Installing rpy2 on windows

Tags: python, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 on a machine running Windows 10. I have already installed R 3.4.4 (64bit) and it works fine in RGui. I then tried to pip install rpy2, but was getting an error that it couldn't find R, so I added c:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.4\bin\ to my path environment variable. Now when I do

```
pip install rpy2
```

I get a different error:

> Command '('c:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.4\bin\x64\R', 'CMD', 'config', '--ldflags')' returned non-zero exit status 1

The full output is given below. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

```
pip install rpy2

Collecting rpy2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/f7/788e5e1587bc1ab48b5b0467f9c3a08ef5aadbd993ed835559a10e452121/rpy2-2.9.3.tar.gz (193kB)
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
c:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.4\bin\x64\R CMD config --ldflags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\py\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qz4rb_4o\rpy2\setup.py", line 374, in <module>
    ri_ext = getRinterface_ext()
  File "C:\Users\py\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qz4rb_4o\rpy2\setup.py", line 269, in getRinterface_ext
    ldf = shlex.split(' '.join(rexec.cmd_config('--ldflags')))
  File "C:\Users\py\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qz4rb_4o\rpy2\setup.py", line 222, in cmd_config
    universal_newlines = True)
  File "c:\users\py\miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\users\py\miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('c:\\PROGRA~1\\R\\R-34~1.4\\bin\\x64\\R', 'CMD', 'config', '--ldflags')' returned non-zero exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\py\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qz4rb_4o\rpy2\
```

Comment: What does `"c:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.4\bin\x64\R" CMD config --ldflags` output when run from *cmd*? Also, is your *Python* 64bit?

Comment: If I just try to run
"c:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.4\bin\x64\R" CMD config --ldflags
from cmd is says

'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I believe python is 64bit: platform.architecture() returns ('64bit', 'WindowsPE') and sys.maxsize is 9223372036854775807

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output contains the error:

> 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command

but I thought it was only a warning (as there was output coming after it).
*sh* (*Shell*) is *Nix* specific and (naturally) doesn't exist on *Win*. However, if you install a port for *Win*, or an *Nix* *env* emulator (like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com), [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org), ...), it might work.

<s>Here's what [[ReadTheDocs.RPy2]: Installation](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/overview.html#installation) (which has "*Compiling on Linux*" and "*Compiling on OS X*" sections, but nothing about *Win*, although it mentions that it should compile successfully) states</s>:

> - There is currently no binaries or support for Microsoft Windows (more for lack of resources than anything else).

> - Microsoft’s Windows - unofficial and unsupported binaries are provided by Christoph Gohlke ([http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs)); there is otherwise currently close to no support for this platform

---

#### Update *#0*

Adding steps that @pyguy took (from comment), in order to successfully install *RPy2*:

- Download *rpy2‑2.9.3‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl* (or any newer version that might have been added in the meantime) from [[UCI.LFD]: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2) (for *032bit* (*pc032*), download the **win32.whl*)
- Open a *Cmd* window (as **Administrator**) in the *.whl*'s download *dir*
- Set ***R_USER*** *env var* to current username:

  ```
  set R_USER=%USERNAME%
  ```
- Install the *.whl* locally:

  ```
  python -m pip install rpy2‑2.9.3‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
  ```

  *Python*'s (binary) *dir* must be in *%PATH%*, or specify the full path.
  Check [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890705/4788546) (***Shortcut*** section (close to the end)), or (referenced) [[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546) for details regarding custom *.whl* installation

Comment: Thanks. I also thought the 'sh' thing was a warning and that it wasn't relevant to windows. And on the rpy2 install instructions, the section "Install from source" didn't mention this doesn't work for windows - guess this was meant to be clear from the preceding comments on windows (and probably is clear to someone more knowledgeable).

Comment: In case someone is interested, I managed to get rpy2 installed on windows as follows (I am using python 3.5.2).

1. download the correct wheel file from the Christoph Gohlke link above (I downloaded rpy2-2.9.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl)  
2. open a cmd window as administrator and cd to the directory containing the wheel  
3. run 'pip install rpy2-2.9.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl'  
4. create a new user environment variable R_USER set to your windows username

Comment: Thank you! I added the steps to the answer so they are more visible.