# How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package-managers

I currently have Python 3.7.4(64 bit) and Python 3.6.6(64 bit) on a **Windows 10** 64 bit laptop with both versions in my system environment variables(path).

I previously only had 3.7 and installed 3.6 to use `pocketsphinx`, and now I want to upgrade `PyAudio` of my 3.6. doing `pip install --upgrade pyaudio` is upgrading the `pyaudio` of 3.7. So, how do i upgrade(or even install) packages of specific python versions on a windows machine?

Here's also what I've tried:
`python-3.6.6 pip install --upgrade pyaudio`,
`python3.6.6 pip install --upgrade pyaudio`,
`python3.6 pip install --upgrade pyaudio` and
`pip3.6.6 install --upgrade pyaudio`.
Yes, these may be stupid, but I was helpless.

**EDIT 1:**
I also run `pip install --upgrade pyaudio` in power shell by opening it in the directory where my python 3.6 is installed, which is(default installation directory for windows): `C:\Users\--user-name--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36` like:
[image: this is what's happening and it's not working]
as you can see from the version, `pip install` would still install new packages for python 3.7

Comment: Is there a *python.exe* in that directory? If yes, can you launch it by `.\python --version`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The golden rule when one wants to access one of the multiple software versions (applies to any software (other than *Python*), on **any *OS***) existing on a machine: **use absolute paths**.

There are multiple ways of `pip install`ing (especially when involving *VEnv*s):

1. Run *PIP* directly - most frequently used:

   ```bat
   pip install --upgrade pyaudio
   ```
2. **Run `python -m pip`**:

   ```bat
   python -m pip install --upgrade pyaudio
   ```
3. Run other convenience wrappers (***Py*** (*Win* specific): [[Python.Docs]: Using Python on Windows - From the command-line](https://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#from-the-command-line)):

   ```bat
   py -3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pyaudio
   ```

But the form that I prefer (as it **will always work** - because it doesn't rely on environment variables like *PATH*), is the **2<sup>nd</sup> one**:

```bat
"${PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON_3_6}" -m pip install --upgrade pyaudio
```

where ***${PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON_3_6}*** is just a placeholder for the actual *Python 3.6* executable path (*e.g.* *%ProgramFiles%\Python 3.6\python.exe*).
Note that **this works fine** (end easy) when having multiple *Python* versions installed (custom built, *VEnv*s, ...).
Check [[Python.Docs]: Using Python on Windows - Installing Without UI](https://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui) for more details regarding install paths.

Generalizing:

```sh
"${PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" -m pip install ${PACKAGE_NAME}
```

where *${PACKAGE_NAME}* is (obviously) the package name.
Note that sometimes, due to special conditions (like local *PIP* repositories configuration, ...), the installation would have to be done in 2 steps:

1. Download the *.whl* locally
2. Pass it to *PIP* (in order to install it)

as described in [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890705/4788546) (*Shortcut* section (somewhere at the end)).

***${PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}*** (using ***v3.9*** as an example) can be (from my machines):

- *Win*:

  - *%ProgramFiles%\Python 3.9\python.exe*
  - *E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe*
  - *F:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\python.exe*
- *Nix*:

  - */usr/bin/python3.9*
  - */opt/qti-aic/dev/python/qaic-env/bin/python*

When not sure about an executable location (actually not limited to executables), that can be checked:

- *Win*: [[MS.Docs]: where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where) (`where /?`)
- *Nix*: [[Die.Linux]: which(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) (`man which`).
  Worth mentioning *alias*es: [[Man7]: ALIAS(1P)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/alias.1p.html) (`man alias`)

Might also worth reading:

- [[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to update pywin32 automatically? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499867/4788546)
- [[SO]: PyAudio.write SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73691382/4788546)

Answer (score 7):

In CMD or powershell ,

for installing in Python 3.7:-

```
>py -3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pyaudio
```

for installing in Python 3.6:-

```
>py -3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pyaudio
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Please use the `-m` flag, when binding to the specific `python`,

```
$ py3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pyaudio
```

From the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#windows) and is the recommended way to install modules,

> The Python installers for Windows include pip. You should be able to
>   access pip using:
>
> py -m pip --version pip 9.0.1 from c:\python36\lib\site-packages
>   (Python 3.6.1)
>
> You can make sure that pip is up-to-date by running:
>
> py -m pip install --upgrade pip

But i recommend you use some virtualenv for this.