# How to install pywin32 without admin rights?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to use the library win32com on Python version 3.7.4 but I don't have administrator rights (only user admin rights I believe).

I also have the version 2.7.15 installed (which I can't uninstall) from when I did had admin rights and tried Python for my first time. That is the version that shows when I run the command `python --version` on the cmd console, so if I try to run the command `python -m pip install pywin32` it does install but on that version and throws a warning that it will be deprecated January 1st, 2020.

So I'm trying to do it manually by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13271241). I downloaded [pywin32-225-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (8.4 MB)](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files), unzipped to a [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCIj7.png) and now I'm not sure what to do.

The Python folder is at:

> %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32

Comment: `pip install pywin32-225-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl` should do

Comment: @Saharsh on cmd pip is not recognized as a command and trying `python -m pip install pywin32-225-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl` installs it on Python version 2.7

Comment: that's probably because you have both Python2 and Python3 installed. Try pinning the location of `Python3.exe` and execute the command that @CristiFati have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the package in the user directory, by passing ***--user***:

```bat
"${FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON37_EXECUTABLE}" -m pip install --user pywin32
```

where *${FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON37_EXECUTABLE}* **is just a placeholder** (in your case it seems to be *C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe*).

More details on [[PyPA.PIP]: pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install) (`pip install -h`).

Note: This is a duplicate of [[SO]: How to install a package for specific version on python on windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546), but since that question has neither an accepted nor an upvoted answer, I can't mark this one as such.

Comment: Running that command installs it on Python 2.7, I want to install on 3.7

Comment: I tried `${"C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32"}\python -m pip install --user pywin32` but it says that the syntax name of the directory is incorrect. I also tried with \\ and / instead of \.

Comment: :) Edited again (I wasn't clear enough, that's just a placeholder).

Comment: Thanks. It worked with `"C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" -m pip install --user pywin32`.