# ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, python-3.7

Importing from `pyxdameraulevenshtein` gives the following error, I have

```
pyxdameraulevenshtein==1.5.3
pandas==1.1.4
scikit-learn==0.20.2.
```

Numpy is 1.16.1.

Works well in Python 3.6, Issue in Python 3.7.

Has anyone been facing similar issues with Python 3.7 (3.7.9), docker image `python:3.7-buster`?

```
from pyxdameraulevenshtein import normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance as norm_dl_dist
__init__.pxd:242: in init pyxdameraulevenshtein
    ???
E   ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

Comment: I'm not competent to post a good answer myself, but none of the current answers seem to contain a good analysis of the root cause for this problem. We need an answer which explains what's wrong and how to figure out how to solve it, rather than a scattershot collection of "try upgrading / downgrading package X, Y, or Z" answers.

Answer (score 337):

I'm in Python 3.8.5. It sounds too simple to be real, but I had this same issue and all I did was reinstall numpy. Gone.

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

or

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Hahaha...I can't believe this worked for me too! For more info, I am also in Python 3.8.5. It looks like I originally had `numpy-1.19.5` and then after the uninstall-install steps I got `numpy-1.20.1 `

Comment: I had to do pip install --upgrade numpy to get it upgraded.

Comment: Classic unplug it and plug it back in solution. Works more often than you'd think.

Comment: Same here - uninstall and install worked for me (root cause might have been the Anaconda env on AWS using version 1.18.5 of numpy)

Comment: what about if you are using conda and not pip?

Comment: had the same issue. this solution worked for me

Comment: Why the "OR" method?

Comment: Worked for me too, Python 3.9.14.

Comment: pip install --upgrade numpy it worked for me thanks  ))^_^)) .

Answer (score 51):

try with `numpy==1.20.0` this worked here, even though other circumstances are different (python3.8 on alpine 3.12).

Comment: `numpy==1.20.1` is already out with bugfixes :-)

Comment: got the same issues, fixed by upgrading numpy to 1.20.3

Comment: Fixed  with ```numpy==1.20.3```

Answer (score 43):

Indeed, (building and) installing with `numpy>=1.20.0` should work, as pointed out e.g. by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066058/11589255). However, I thought some background might be interesting -- and provide also alternative solutions.

There was a [change in the C API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html#size-of-np-ndarray-and-np-void-changed) in `numpy 1.20.0`. In some cases, `pip` seems to download the latest version of `numpy` for the build stage, but then the program is run with the installed version of `numpy`. If the build version used in `<1.20`, but the installed version is `=>1.20`, this will lead to an error.

(The other way around it should not matter, because of backwards compatibility. But if one uses an installed version `numpy<1.20`, they did not anticipate the upcoming change.)

This leads to several possible ways to solve the problem:

- upgrade (the build version) to `numpy>=1.20.0`
- use *minmum supported numpy* version in `pyproject.toml` (`oldest-supported-numpy`)
- install with `--no-binary`
- install with `--no-build-isolation`

For a more detailed discussion of potential solutions, see
https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/457#issuecomment-773671043.

Comment: _If the build version used in <1.20, but the installed version is =>1.20, this will lead to an error._
Isn't that the other way around? You build with a newer version that doesn't have the header definition and then run it with an older version that expects the header definition. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @IvayloToskov: Although it doesn't seem intuitive, I think that it is correct: The build version is responsible for the compilation. The old build versions could not anticipate that there will be a change in numpy, so this type of setup creates a problem.

Comment: After some verification, I can confirm that it is indeed the other way around. The change in the C API is forwards compatible, since you are removing a header. If you build with an older version that has the header and run it with a newer version, it won't break.
The following sequence produces the error:
`pip install numpy==1.21.0`,
`pip install pycocotools --no-binary pycocotools`,
`pip install numpy==1.19.2`,
`python -c "import pycocotools.coco.COCO"`
So the error occurs when the build version is `>=1.20` and the runtime version is `<1.20`.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no "above" or "below". The sort order of the answers depends on each individual visitor's display preferences.

Comment: This answer is currently the closest to an explanation of what's wrong, but I feel it needs more details in the concrete steps one would take to establish which NumPy version exactly to target to solve the problem. There seems to have been another change in the ABI recently with a slightly different error message (the number of bytes changed once more) and I expect it to happen again in the future.

Comment: @tripleee I think [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/16938/files) is the commit that introduced the problem in numpy, hope this help

Comment: @Hicomputer That's useful for this particular version bump, but I'm looking for a general solution for how to find out when this ABI changed and which version to target when you get a particular error message.

Comment: I think that error message is a little confusing

Comment: @tripleee You can check my answer to see if it brings more clarity. If I have to generalise the issue, the problem comes when you install a version of (usually) newer numpy with a specific C API, build another package against this new version, then downgrade numpy to a version which isn't compatible with the other package. Then at runtime the usage of the other package results in this error. Overall the generic solution is to build packages against a specific numpy version and then use this same numpy version when running your code. This is the reason why the upgrade usually helps.

Comment: @IvayloToskov I like your answer, too, but it wasn't obvious to me when I posted the bounty that it really answered the question. Now with more information I'm beginning to see that maybe it does; but I'm thinking it would still need some polish to make it more obvious if indeed it solves the general case.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, indeed. I think I will add some more information on how some packages are being built, as well as how pip's dependency resolution works.

Comment: Please don't be upset that I awarded the bounty to the new answer. This one is great, too.

Answer (score 30):

### Solution without upgrading `numpy`

While upgrading the `numpy` version would often solve the issue, it's not always viable. Good example is the case when you're using `tensorflow==2.6.0` which isn't compatible with the newest `numpy` version (it requires `~=1.19.2`).

As already mentioned in [FZeiser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66743692/2572994), there was a change in `numpy`s C API in version `1.20.0`. There are packages that rely on this C API when they are being built, e.g. `pyxdameraulevenshtein`. Given that `pip`s dependency resolver doesn't guarantee any order for installing the packages, the following might happen:

1. `pip` figures out that it needs to install `numpy` and it chooses the latest version, `1.21.2` as of the time writing this answer.
2. It then builds a package that depends on `numpy` and its C API, e.g. `pyxdameraulevenshtein`. This package is now compatible with `numpy 1.21.2` C API.
3. At a later point `pip` needs to install a package that has a requirement for an older version of `numpy`, e.g. `tensorflow==2.6.0` which would try to install `numpy==1.19.5`. As a result, `numpy==1.21.2` is uninstalled and the older version is installed.
4. When running code that uses `pyxdameraulevenshtein`, its current installation relies on the updated `numpy` C API, yet the `numpy` version was downgraded which would result in the error.

#### Solution

You should rebuild the package with the outdated `numpy` C API usage to make sure it's compatible with the currently installed version of `numpy`. E.g. for `pyxdameraulevenshtein`:

```
pip uninstall pyxdameraulevenshtein
pip install pyxdameraulevenshtein --no-binary pyxdameraulevenshtein
```

Comment: I am in the situation you describe, however, when using pycocotools 2.0.4 the error persisted after using this method, but if I downgraded to version 2.0.0 as suggested by @royce schultz the problem resolved. Which version of pycocotools where you using?

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but looking at the release history and the time of this answer, I think it was `2.0.2`. I cannot reproduce the problem with Python 3.8 though for some reason. What is your environment? Python, `pip` and `setuptools` versions?

Comment: I'm using python 3.8.10, pip 21.3.1, I didn't find setuptools or easy_tools using pip freeze, but when I ran 'pip install setuptools' it said v 58.5.2 was installed

Answer (score 23):

I had this issue when using the tensorflow object api. Tensorflow is currently NOT compatible with numpy==1.20 (although this issue is not apparent until later).
In my case, the issue was caused by pycocotools. I fixed by installing an older version.

```
pip install pycocotools==2.0.0
```

Comment: It has its own problem - when installing it removes the existing cython installation and then outputs ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

Comment: it didn't remove cython in my case. everything worked great!

Comment: This was my exact problem too. In my case worked well and didn't remove Cython.

Comment: You even know what you did, you just helped me fix a problem that blocked me for 3 days

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was:

```
pip uninstall numpy
conda install -y -c conda-forge numpy
```

As bizarre as it might sound... I didn't even have to uninstall it with Conda which seemed odd to me. I am using python 3.9

Comment: The upvotes suggest that this helped some users, but many of us are not Anaconda users in the first place, and it's unclear under what circumstances this arrangement could actually help.

Comment: works for me (on Mac M1 pro)

Answer (score 8):

Upgrading python version to numpy ==1.21.1 worked for me!

Comment: Yup for binary incompatibility upgrading or downgrading packages is helpful.

Answer (score 8):

This is a more detailed version of [[SO]: ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject - (@FZeiser's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66743692/4788546) (great answer *BTW*).

In short, **it's an *ABI* change** (in *NumPy*).
As a consequence, under no circumstances, 2 versions (with **and** without the change) should be mixed together.
The error message (misleading for some users) comes from *PyxDamerauLevenshtein*.

#### 1. *NumPy*

[[NumPy]: NumPy **1.20.0** Release Notes - Size of np.ndarray and np.void_ changed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html#size-of-np-ndarray-and-np-void-changed) states:

> The size of the *PyArrayObject* and *PyVoidScalarObject* structures have changed. The following header definition has been removed:
>
> ```c
> #define NPY_SIZEOF_PYARRAYOBJECT (sizeof(PyArrayObject_fields))
> ```
>
> since the size must not be considered a compile time constant: it will change for different runtime versions of NumPy.
>
> The most likely relevant use are potential subclasses written in C which will have to be recompiled and should be updated. Please see the documentation for [PyArrayObject](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/types-and-structures.html#c.PyArrayObject) for more details and contact the NumPy developers if you are affected by this change.
>
> NumPy will attempt to give a graceful error but a program expecting a fixed structure size may have undefined behaviour and likely crash.

[[GitHub]: numpy/numpy - (**v1.19.5**) numpy/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#726](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.5/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L726):

```c
#define NPY_SIZEOF_PYARRAYOBJECT (sizeof(PyArrayObject_fields))
```

is the **last one** that has it, in the subsequent versions, starting with ***v1.20.0*** (and its preceding *RC*s), the line is commented out.
Also worth mentioning here that between the same versions, a new member has been added to (the end of) *PyArrayObject_fields* structure (~20 lines above):

```c
void *_buffer_info;  /* private buffer info, tagged to allow warning */
```

The numbers in the error message (*80* and *88*) are beginning to make some sense.

**There's a boundary between the (above) 2 versions: anything that is built with one version and ran with the other is an unsupported scenario**. It's just like misusing any other library: building with (headers and *.so* (*.lib*) from) one version and running with (the *.so* (*.dll*) from) another one - when the 2 versions are *API* / *ABI* incompatible.

2 cases emerge:

1. Build: *v >= v1.20.0*, Run: *v <= v1.19.5*: unsupported
2. Build: *v <= v1.19.5*, Run: *v >= v1.20.0*: technically also unsupported, but since there's no more value computed at compile (preprocess) time ([[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546)), it would work

[[GitHub]: numpy/numpy - ENH,API: Store exported buffer info on the array](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/af4b110273346e5969fba04365bc477747529fe2) <sup>***(1)***</sup> is the commit that introduced the changes.

#### 2. *PyxDamerauLevenshtein*

[[GitHub]: lanl/pyxDamerauLevenshtein - pyxDamerauLevenshtein](https://github.com/lanl/pyxDamerauLevenshtein) is an extension module (*C* + *Cython*) that depends on *NumPy*. The source code (indirectly) includes *ndarraytypes.h*.

Browsing [[PyPI]: pyxDamerauLevenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/pyxDamerauLevenshtein) (latest versions at least) there's only one binary: for *OSX* *pc064*, and one *Python* version (probably the *LTS* at package publish time).
As a consequence, on all other platforms when `pip install`ed, it's **built from sources**.

For simplicity's sake, **will use *v1.5.3*** (like in the question).
As a side note, although *setup.py* requires *NumPy* *>= v1.16.1*, there is a *requirements.txt* file which contains *v1.16.1* as a dependency (which is a bit misleading - especially when shallowly investigating).

The error message was added in *v1.5.1* (specifically for this *NumPy* *ABI* change), and it was then removed in *v1.7.0* when trying to move away from depending on *NumPy* at build time. I suppose it is because of the nightmare generated by the frequency of running into this situation (other packages depending on specific *NumPy* versions).
Removal commit: [[GitHub]: lanl/pyxDamerauLevenshtein - first attempt of moving away from NumPy](https://github.com/lanl/pyxDamerauLevenshtein/commit/cddec9bd275abc0ef4f5ecc9fd4e79a6d6cc120e).

#### 3. Example

Once the theory is figured out, it's not hard to reproduce the problem.
Steps:

- Install *NumPy* ***<= v1.19.5*** (*v1.19.5*)
- Install *PyxDamerauLevenshtein* ***v1.5.3***

I prepared my "demo" on *Win*, as it happens to be the *OS* that I currently booted into.
There are also some additional commands to capture the state (at several points) in the process. Also some (unimportant) output will be stripped out:

> ```
> (py_pc064_03.07_test1_q066060487) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066060487]> :: Python 3.7 console
> (py_pc064_03.07_test1_q066060487) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066060487]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -c "import sys;print(\"\n\".join((sys.executable, sys.version)))"
> E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07_test1_q066060487\Scripts\python.exe
> 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip freeze
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip install numpy==1.19.5
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
> Collecting numpy==1.19.5
>   Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (13.2 MB)
>      ---------------------------------------- 13.2/13.2 MB 8.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
> Installing collected packages: numpy
> Successfully installed numpy-1.19.5
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip freeze
> numpy==1.19.5
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Pass -v to see what is actually going on. I`ll truncate some output
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip install -v pyxdameraulevenshtein==1.5.3
> Using pip 22.3.1 from E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07_test1_q066060487\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
> Collecting pyxdameraulevenshtein==1.5.3
>   Downloading pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.tar.gz (58 kB)
>      ---------------------------------------- 58.5/58.5 kB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
>   Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
>   Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
>   Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
>     Downloading setuptools-66.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
>        ---------------------------------------- 1.3/1.3 MB 5.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
>   Collecting wheel>=0.33.1
>     Downloading wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
>   Collecting numpy>=1.16.1
>     Downloading numpy-1.21.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (14.0 MB)
>        ---------------------------------------- 14.0/14.0 MB 9.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
>   Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, numpy
>
>   # @TODO - cfati: !!! Check NumPy version used at build time !!!
>
>   Successfully installed numpy-1.21.6 setuptools-66.0.0 wheel-0.38.4
>   Installing build dependencies ... done
>   Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
>   running egg_info
>
>   # @TODO - cfati: Truncated output
>
>    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.1 in e:\work\dev\venvs\py_pc064_03.07_test1_q066060487\lib\site-packages (from pyxdameraulevenshtein==1.5.3) (1.19.5)
> Building wheels for collected packages: pyxdameraulevenshtein
>   Running command Building wheel for pyxdameraulevenshtein (pyproject.toml)
>   running bdist_wheel
>   running build
>   running build_ext
>   building 'pyxdameraulevenshtein' extension
>   creating build
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein
>   C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o_18jg2s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IE:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07_test1_q066060487\include -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07\include -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07\Include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" 
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcpyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.obj
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein.c
>   C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o_18jg2s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2240): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2271): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2358): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2434): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2957): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
>   creating C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t79ijgrr\pyxdameraulevenshtein_4dee1beb9a9542bb89a45fc96b191728\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
>   C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07_test1_q066060487\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07 /LIBPATH:E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07_test1_q066060487\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\lib\x64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22000.0\\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_pyxdameraulevenshtein build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp37
> -win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein\pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp37-win_amd64.lib
>      Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein\pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein\pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp37-win_amd64.exp
>   Generating code
>   Finished generating code
>   installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
>  
>   # @TODO - cfati: Truncated output
>
>   running install_scripts
>   creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info\WHEEL
>   creating 'C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-g6cfcj3b\.tmp-n2i1vw8v\pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel' to it
>   adding 'pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
>   adding 'pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info/METADATA'
>   adding 'pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info/WHEEL'
>   adding 'pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info/top_level.txt'
>   adding 'pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info/RECORD'
>   removing build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
>   C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o_18jg2s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py:83: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
>     if get_flag("Py_DEBUG", hasattr(sys, "gettotalrefcount"), warn=(impl == "cp")):
>   C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o_18jg2s\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py:89: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
>     warn=(impl == "cp" and sys.version_info < (3, 8)),
>   Building wheel for pyxdameraulevenshtein (pyproject.toml) ... done
>   Created wheel for pyxdameraulevenshtein: filename=pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl size=24372 sha256=ced6c506896c3b1d98f8ddd165b4bf8a399287fd9f5543f2398953b479173e86
>   Stored in directory: C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-6epkbo0t\wheels\b4\f5\9e\39cf91e589064ceb8a4db3b6d9b2c7f267af79f9542f2ddbb3
> Successfully built pyxdameraulevenshtein
> Installing collected packages: pyxdameraulevenshtein
> Successfully installed pyxdameraulevenshtein-1.5.3
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Existing NumPy version (used at runtime)
> [prompt]> python -m pip freeze
> numpy==1.19.5
> pyxDamerauLevenshtein==1.5.3
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -c "from pyxdameraulevenshtein import normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance;print(\"Done.\")"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "__init__.pxd", line 242, in init pyxdameraulevenshtein
> ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip install numpy==1.20.0
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
> Collecting numpy==1.20.0
>   Downloading numpy-1.20.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (13.6 MB)
>      ---------------------------------------- 13.6/13.6 MB 7.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
> Installing collected packages: numpy
>   Attempting uninstall: numpy
>     Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
>     Uninstalling numpy-1.19.5:
>       Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.19.5
> Successfully installed numpy-1.20.0
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip freeze
> numpy==1.20.0
> pyxDamerauLevenshtein==1.5.3
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -c "from pyxdameraulevenshtein import normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance;print(\"Done.\")"
> Done.
> ```

The cause is pretty clear (although is hidden in the verbose output): **when building *PyxDamerauLevenshtein*, *PIP* (silently and temporarily) downloads (and uses for build) *NumPy* *v1.21.6* (in this case), ignoring the existing installed version**. Then, at runtime *v1.19.5* is used, hence the error.

**Note**: **The problem is no longer reproducible with newest *PyxDamerauLevenshtein* version (*v1.7.1* at answer time)**.

#### 4. A twist

As mentioned in the question, things seem to work for *Python 3.**6***.

At the beginning I was thinking that this part of the commit (<sup>***#1***</sup>) is the culprit:

```diff
+     if (_buffer_info_free(fa->_buffer_info, (PyObject *)self) < 0) {
+         PyErr_WriteUnraisable(NULL);
+     }
```

[[Python.**3.7**.Docs]: void PyErr_WriteUnraisable(PyObject *obj)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_WriteUnraisable) states (for *v3.7*, **but not for *v3.6***):

> An exception must be set when calling this function.

From there, in [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (**v3.7.0**) cpython/Python/errors.c#206](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Python/errors.c#L206), *PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches* seems to be stricter than in ***v3.6.15***, and that's why no exception is raised when passing *NULL*.

But I was wrong, things are waaay simpler:

> ```
> (py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066060487]> :: Python 3.6 console
> (py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q066060487]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -c "import sys;print(\"\n\".join((sys.executable, sys.version)))"
> e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\Scripts\python.exe
> 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip freeze
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip install numpy==1.19.5
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
> Collecting numpy==1.19.5
>   Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (13.2 MB)
>      |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 13.2 MB 1.6 MB/s
> Installing collected packages: numpy
> Successfully installed numpy-1.19.5
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip freeze
> numpy==1.19.5
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Pass -v (again) to see what is actually going on. I`ll truncate some output
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip install -v pyxdameraulevenshtein==1.5.3
> Using pip 21.3.1 from e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
> Collecting pyxdameraulevenshtein==1.5.3
>   Downloading pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.tar.gz (58 kB)
>      |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 58 kB 1.6 MB/s
>   Running command 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\Scripts\python.exe' 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6hif14f\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com --trusted-host pypi.ngc.nvidia.com -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' 'wheel>=0.33.1' 'numpy>=1.16.1'
>   Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
>   Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
>     Downloading setuptools-59.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
>   Collecting wheel>=0.33.1
>     Downloading wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
>   Collecting numpy>=1.16.1
>     Downloading numpy-1.19.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (13.2 MB)
>   Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, numpy
>   Successfully installed numpy-1.19.5 setuptools-59.6.0 wheel-0.37.1
>   Installing build dependencies ... done
>   Running command 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\Scripts\python.exe' 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfdchqls9'
>   running egg_info
>
>   # @TODO - cfati: Truncated output
>
>   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.1 in e:\work\dev\venvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\lib\site-packages (from pyxdameraulevenshtein==1.5.3) (1.19.5)
> Building wheels for collected packages: pyxdameraulevenshtein
>   Running command 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\Scripts\python.exe' 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0_edf2js'
>   running bdist_wheel
>   running build
>   running build_ext
>   building 'pyxdameraulevenshtein' extension
>   creating build
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
>   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein
>   C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6hif14f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.06.08\include -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.06.08\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\in
> clude\um" /Tcpyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.obj
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein.c
>   C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6hif14f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2240): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2271): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2358): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2434): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
>   pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.c(2957): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
>   creating C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jbo5i6wm\pyxdameraulevenshtein_f0a231227bfc404898102cc0b821c01c\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
>   C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.06.08\Libs /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\libs /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.06_test1_q066060487\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\lib\x64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22000.0\\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_pyxdameraulevenshtein build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein/pyxdameraulevenshtein.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\p
> yxdameraulevenshtein\pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp36-win_amd64.lib
>      Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein\pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyxdameraulevenshtein\pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp36-win_amd64.exp
>   Generating code
>   Finished generating code
>   installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
>
>   # @TODO - cfati: Truncated output
>
>   running install_scripts
>   creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info\WHEEL
>   creating 'C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-wpe1zd_h\tmpdhak06i5\pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel' to it
>   adding 'pyxdameraulevenshtein.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
>   adding 'pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info/METADATA'
>   adding 'pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info/WHEEL'
>   adding 'pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info/top_level.txt'
>   adding 'pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3.dist-info/RECORD'
>   removing build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
>   C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6hif14f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py:82: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
>     warn=(impl == 'cp')):
>   C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h6hif14f\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py:87: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
>     sys.version_info < (3, 8))) \
>   Building wheel for pyxdameraulevenshtein (pyproject.toml) ... done
>   Created wheel for pyxdameraulevenshtein: filename=pyxDamerauLevenshtein-1.5.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl size=27385 sha256=e17febb7db9cbe5e7726c486367b189bbd8b07d93c845ab580ee69f652eed002
>   Stored in directory: C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-g6lraow9\wheels\ab\e3\f3\34dfd385a44f053693d576e00ea4a6f4beb73366f7237271cf
> Successfully built pyxdameraulevenshtein
> Installing collected packages: pyxdameraulevenshtein
> Successfully installed pyxdameraulevenshtein-1.5.3
>   Link requires a different Python (3.6.8 not in: '>=3.7'): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/8b/a094f5da22d7abf5098205367b3296dd15b914f4232af5ca39ba6214d08c/pip-22.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=6cb1ea2bd7fda0668e26ae8c3e45188f301a7ef17ff22efe1f70f3643e56a822 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pip/) (requires-python:>=3.7)
>
>   # @TODO - cfati: Truncated output 
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -m pip freeze
> numpy==1.19.5
> pyxDamerauLevenshtein==1.5.3
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> python -c "from pyxdameraulevenshtein import normalized_damerau_levenshtein_distance;print(\"Done.\")"
> Done.
> ```

So, on *Python 3.6*, this scenario can't be encountered, since **the newest (built) *NumPy* version is *v1.19.5***.

#### 5. Conclusions

I ran in this (simplified) scenario (*MCVE*) intentionally, to prove a point.
Normal user would typically reach it when installing a package that depends on an older *NumPy* version. But since newer package versions (with newer dependents versions) keep appearing, the chance of running into it fades away as time passes by.

However, if someone does run into it, here are a bunch of (generic) guidelines to overcome it:

1. Install (upgrade) *NumPy* ***>= v1.20.0*** (preferably) **before installing *PyxDamerauLevenshtein*** (or better: don't use an older version anymore)
2. Install *PyxDamerauLevenshtein* ***>= v1.7.0***
3. Instruct *PIP* ([[PyPA.PIP]: pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install)) not to upgrade dependents
4. Build *PyxDamerauLevenshtein* "manually" (`python setup.py build`), as in that case I noticed that existing *NumPy* version is used (this is what one would expect (and *PIP* is not used))

- Note that this may be applicable to other packages as well, and also there might be additional restrictions involved
- **All in all**

  - **Check**:

    - After installing all required packages (that might downgrade *NumPy* to *<= v1.19.5*)
    - Constantly (if package installation is a continuous process)

    the *NumPy* version (`pythnon -m pip freeze`), and if it's the case, **upgrade** it (`python -m pip upgrade numpy`)

Related (more or less):

- [[SO]: How to fix error during pythonnet installation (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73805010/4788546)
- [[SO]: Can't install pyo using pip (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73512700/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546)
- [[SO]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/4788546)

Comment: Thanks for a really thorough investigation! It would be nice if there was a "TLDR" at the top and perhaps a comparison to FZeiser's answer. As it currently stands, this is a nice complement to theirs, but probably inaccessible to beginners.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) it is necessary to have `experimental.new-installer` set to `true` for an application with a `numpy<1.20` dependency to be built correctly i.e:

```
poetry config experimental.new-installer true
```

It is `true` by default but if (as was the case for me) it has been changed it can catch you out.

My application uses Tensorflow and I did not therefore have the option of upgrading to `>1.20`. Poetry also does not support `--no-binary` dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

numpy version 1.22 solved it for me.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing same issue in raspberry pi 3. Actually the error is with `pandas`. Although tensorflow need `numpy~=1.19.2` , but `pandas` is not compliable with it. So, I have upgraded (because downgrading is not) my `numpy` to latest version and all works fine!!!!.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> np.__version__
'1.21.5'
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.3.5'
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'2.4.0'
>>> tf.keras.__version__
'2.4.0'
>>> tf.keras.layers
<module 'tensorflow.keras.layers' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/keras/layers/__init__.py'>
```

Same issue here also - https://github.com/bitsy-ai/tensorflow-arm-bin/issues/5

Tensorflow source: https://github.com/bitsy-ai/tensorflow-arm-bin

Comment: I did this - uninstalled numpy(==1.21.2 that is the version I wanted to recreate a previous environment) and just installed the latest version (1.24.2). It works

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me (when nothing else on this page did):

```
# Create environment with conda or venv.
# Do *not* install any other packages here.
pip install numpy==1.21.5
# Install all other packages here.
# This works as a package may build against the currently installed version of numpy.
```

This solved a particularly brutal issue that was unresolvable by all other answers on this page as of 2022-04-11:

> Other answers try to fix the problem *after* it occurred, this fixes the problem *before* it occurs.

In addition, experiment with different versions of Python, e.g. 3.8, 3.9, 3.10.

Reference: [Excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66743692/7789963) by @FZeiser that explains why this works.

Answer (score 4):

After you pip install any package, makes sure you restart the Kernel and should work. usually packages get upgraded automatically and all you need is a quick restart. At least, this what worked in my situation and I was getting the same error when I tried to install and use pomegranate.

Answer (score 3):

Use python virtual environments and install `gensim` using :

```sh
pip install gensim==3.8.3
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered with the same problem with python3.10.4,numpy1.21.5, I solved it only after I updated numpy to 1.22.3 via pip uninstall numpy and pip install numpy. Only pip install --upgrade numpy didn't work.

> PS D:\quant\vnpy-master\examples\veighna_trader> python .\run.py
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "D:\quant\vnpy-master\examples\veighna_trader\run.py", line 31, in
>  from vnpy_optionmaster import OptionMasterApp File
> "D:\it_soft\python3.10.4\Lib\site-packages\vnpy_optionmaster__init__.py",
> line 26, in  from .engine import OptionEngine, APP_NAME File
> "D:\it_soft\python3.10.4\Lib\site-packages\vnpy_optionmaster\engine.py",
> line 34, in  from .pricing import binomial_tree_cython as
> binomial_tree File "binomial_tree_cython.pyx", line 1, in init
> binomial_tree_cython ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may
> indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88
> from PyObject

Answer (score 1):

For almost the same image : python:3.7-slim-buster

I started to have this problem just today, it was non exitent before.

I solved it by removing numpy from requirement.txt file and doing instead the following in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip3 install --upgrade  --no-binary numpy==1.18.1 numpy==1.18.1 \
&& pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I use some old versions of keras and its librairies and updrading to numpy 1.20.0 didn't work for those librairies. But I think the solution consist in the first command that I gave you wich tell pip to try to not compile numpy and download a pre-compiled version.

The trick in the command is that you might find people telling you to use --no-binary option of pip to solve the problem, but they don't specify how and it might be tricky (as it happened to me); you have  to write the package two times in the command in order for it to work or else pip will throw you an error.

I think the --upgrade option in the first command isn't necessary.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but upgrading to 1.20.0 did, even though the error I got was in the context of loading a library that was compiled against an earlier version of numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade numpy version:

```
pip install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue but could not update numpy because of some incompatibility conflict with another package that I needed which requires `numpy<=1.21.0`. The error `numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility` was generated from a personal package. The solution was to modify the `pyproject.toml` file of my package and set :

```
requires = ["numpy==1.21.0", <other packages>]
```

which was previously set to `"numpy>=1.21.0"`, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Install older version of gensim, It works!

```
pip install gensim==3.5.0
```

or

```
conda install gensim==3.5.0
```