# pip install --no-deps --no-build-isolation -r requirements.txt still appears to use unlisted dependencies

Tags: python, numpy, pip, parquet, python-packaging

I'm running into an issue with `pip install --no-deps --no-build-isolation -r requirements.txt` that I would not expect.

As a way of working around Python dependency hell using `pip` (the use of other package managers, e.g., `poetry`, are longer-term projects), we want to freeze our dependencies and install the exact versions of various packages we need.

In the list of dependencies includes:

```
fastparquet==0.4.1
...
numpy==1.17.4
```

The former depends on the latter.

In an attempt to get `fastparquet` to use the version of `numpy` we want, I thought that `pip install --no-deps --no-build-isolation -r requirements.txt` would work. `--no-deps` would ensure that dependencies of the packages listed won't be pulled down by `pip`, and `--no-build-isolation` would ensure we don't build `fastparquet` with a newer version of `numpy` as a result of [pip's build isolation behavior](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#pep-517-and-518-support).

Running `pip install ...` works without error. However, when running my code, I still get this issue when using `fastparquet`:

```
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility.
Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

This error appears to be a [`numpy` version compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp).

Reinstalling `fastparquet==0.4.1` via `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall` fixes the issue, which implies to me that, the first time around, `pip` is still using a newer version of `numpy`.

Note that we are starting from a clean Python virtual environment with neither `numpy` nor `fastparquet` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your analysis makes sense. The build environment and runtime environment are separate. When building fastparquet, the system doesn't know which numpy has been installed, so it just pulled the latest numpy based on its build settings. You may want to install numpy before fastparquet and use --no-build-isolation option.

Have you tried adding the option into requirements.txt?

```
fastparquet==0.4.1, --no-build-isolation
```

This works with pip version larger than 20.2.2