# toad error - numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject

Tags: python, numpy

I just installed `toad-0.0.62` using pip and success

but when I import

`import toad`

the result

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-1831ec789c33> in <module>
----> 1 import toad

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/toad/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .merge import merge, DTMerge, ChiMerge, StepMerge, QuantileMerge, KMeansMerge
      2 from .detector import detect
      3 from .metrics import KS, KS_bucket, F1
      4 from .stats import quality, IV, VIF, WOE, entropy, entropy_cond, gini, gini_cond
      5 from .selection import select

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/toad/merge.pyx in init toad.merge()

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

What I try is upgrade my numpy from `1.19.2` to `1.20.1` (requirement `1.18.0`) but still same error, I'm using `python 3.8.6`

Comment: maybe the solution is to reinstall numpy.
like he did here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp

Comment: Already upgrade  from 1.19.2 to 1.20.1, actually the requirement is 1.18.0

Comment: try removing it all together, and then try to install it from scratch.
sometimes upgrading leave traces of the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the similar issue，when I install `toad-0.0.65`

```
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject

pip install numpy==1.20.1 toad
```

And restart your current notebook for update cache，toad will work.