# Pandas import error on older Numpy version on Raspbian

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

On a fresh install of Raspbian 10 on Raspberry PI 3 B+, I am trying to install with Python 3.7 the `numpy==1.19.5`. The problem is that when I `import pandas`, I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 44 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
```

If I keep the default installation of `numpy==1.20.2`, it works perfectly, but I have a requirement for any numpy version less than `1.20`. I've tried some versions of pandas, but nothing works. I've hit a dead-end so I am asking here for help.

Comment: So this sort of error can be confusing to sort out... but generally comes down to how you're installing the packages. This is not necessarily pandas-specific, so searching for your error message will return some useful links. e.g.,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66743692/9357244 https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5270 I think that providing some more info on how you're installing packages may help (pip? anaconda? from source?).

Comment: I've already looked into this topic you suggested, but it says to upgrade numpy to 1.20 which is not suited in my case. I installed everything with pip3 which is at it's latest version (21.0.1).