# How to you fix the Python error when trying to import talib?

Tags: python

I'm trying to import TA-Lib and keep getting the error below. I'm using Python 3.8 and numpy 1.21. I tried several of the solutions I saw on here but it isn't working. I did download the whl from the this site [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib) for my computer and python. It downloaded sucessfully but when I import I'm getting this error below:

```
import talib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-67-1ee486ccef90>", line 1, in <module>
    
import talib
File "C:\Users\thean\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\talib\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from ._ta_lib import (

  File "talib\_ta_lib.pyx", line 1, in init talib._ta_lib

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp)

Comment: Ironically, all I had to do was log out and log back on and then it worked.