# Value Error with numpy when installed TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am running into this error when i import this

`from gensim.models import KeyedVectors`

the error is

```
  File "c:\Users\frase\eg1.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
  File "C:\Users\frase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\frase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
  File "C:\Users\frase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\indexedcorpus.py", line 14, in <module>
    from gensim import interfaces, utils
  File "C:\Users\frase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gensim\interfaces.py", line 19, in <module>
    from gensim import utils, matutils
  File "C:\Users\frase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py", line 1024, in <module>
    from gensim._matutils import logsumexp, mean_absolute_difference, dirichlet_expectation
  File "gensim/_matutils.pyx", line 1, in init gensim._matutils
    #!/usr/bin/env cython
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

I have used KeyedVectors before to load in a model, but this started to occur when i installed 'TensorFlow'.

I have looked up this issue, and reduced the version of Numpy to 1.19.2 (which is max for Tensorflow), but that did not work. I have also tried to simply uninstall and reinstall and that also has not worked.

Any reason why this is happening?

Example of code used for (NOTE: I can't test it so there might be errors):

```py
    model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
        '\Word2vec\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)

    # create the embedding matrix
    embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, 300))  # 300 is dim size
    for word, vector in model.key_to_vectors():
        if(word in tokenizer.word_index):
            idx = tokenizer.word_index[word]
            embedding_matrix[idx] = np.array(vector, dtype=np.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions.

1. Downgrade python environment to 3.8/3.7
2. uninstall Numpy and upgrade to Latest  NumPy version

Reference- [ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp)