# Unable to import TensorFlow in Python 3.8

Tags: python, tensorflow

1 month ago TensorFlow was working fine. Now I can't import it even. I removed python as well as anaconda along with the base environment files. I reinstalled anaconda and used the Anaconda navigator to install TensorFlow.
Every time, I try to import TensorFlow I get this error in anaconda prompt.

```
(base) C:\Users\Prakhar Sharma>python
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 19 2021, 13:12:57) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training as training_lib
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import data_adapter
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 60, in <module>
    import pandas as pd  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas\_libs\interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
>>>
```

Also, I don't know why is it saying `MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)`. I have Intel i5 and I downloaded the correct installer.
I've TensorFlow 2.3.0.
[see this snip for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLDpw.png)

I have already used `conda update -all` to get the most recent updates.

Comment: Refer this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is related to numpy version.Install latest version of numpy

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```