# Pandas/Numpy version issue - ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`pandas` and `numpy` seem to have version issues on my Debian Linux.

I tried using the `apt install python3-numpy` version, as well as using `pip3` to install version 1.17.3 and 1.21.2. I also tried uninstalling the `pip3` version before trying the `apt` version. All of them seemed to throw errors.

`numpy` itself can be imported but `pandas` complains about `numpy` when you try to import it. I also tried `sudo apt install libatlas3-base`.

In the end, I always get some error like

> ```
>   File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
> ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. 
>   Expected 44 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
> ```

My `pandas` version is 1.3.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp)

Comment: ^ (I'm not sure if any of the above help and I'm sure you've already seen it, just linking it here in case a solution gets found here, it should also go there for future searchability)

Comment: @Kaia Thanks. Correct, I tried the solutions in that one before asking, but good to call out.