# numpy ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting below error when trying to `import fastparquet as fp`
`ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject`

Please help me out to rectify the concern.

Comment: adding the `fastparquet` tag to your question should improve your chances of getting an answer

Answer (score 2):

What is your version of numpy ? In my case simply upgrading numpy to 1.21 (from 1.19) solved the problem:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

You can also find some more complete answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp)

Comment: Thanks your suggestions worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i just deal with it.

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

or

```
 pip uninstall numpy
 pip install numpy
```

***Note***: the operation happen in the Python Interpreter that is used in your current project.