# Importing Gensim in python ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header got 80 from PyObject

Tags: python, numpy, gensim

I am simply doing the following import statements:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

but I keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/COMP34711-NLP-CW2/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
  File "/Users/user/.conda/envs/COMP34711-NLP-CW2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
  File "/Users/user/.conda/envs/COMP34711-NLP-CW2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/corpora/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
  File "/Users/user/.conda/envs/COMP34711-NLP-CW2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/corpora/indexedcorpus.py", line 14, in <module>
    from gensim import interfaces, utils
  File "/Users/user/.conda/envs/COMP34711-NLP-CW2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/interfaces.py", line 19, in <module>
    from gensim import utils, matutils
  File "/Users/user/.conda/envs/COMP34711-NLP-CW2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/matutils.py", line 1024, in <module>
    from gensim._matutils import logsumexp, mean_absolute_difference, dirichlet_expectation
  File "gensim/_matutils.pyx", line 1, in init gensim._matutils
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

I have tried updating my Numpy package (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp) answer) to 1.21.4 (the latest at the time of this post), but I still keep getting the same issue.

***Update:*** It seems like there is a bit of incompatibility between Gensim and Apple's M1 processors as per [these](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues?q=is%3Aissue+m1) github issues opened in the official Gensim repository. [This](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/3226) issue specifically, shows my exact issue with it.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

How did you install `gensim`?

You may want to try uninstalling `gensim` & reinstalling it, *after* the `numpy` was updated, to be sure any installation-time choices/compilations use the updated `numpy`?

If that does not help, you may want to try starting over in a fresh `conda` environment, and being sure to install a fresh `numpy` 1st, then `gensim`.

Comment: That ended up working for me so thank you! I uninstalled numpy and gensim then downladed numpy again with 'pip install -U numpy' and then 'pip install gensim' and the error went away