# Not able to install packages that rely on Tensorflow on Mac M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, apple-m1

I successfully installed Tensorflow 2.7.0 on my MacBook with an M1 chip following this guide by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

I now want to install a package (ethnicolr) in a project that relies on Tensorflow `>=1.15.2`. This should not be an issue, but it sadly is.

*requirements.txt* of my project

```
pandas==1.3.4
ethnicolr==0.4.0
```

*requirements.txt* of ethnicolr:

```
tensorflow>=1.15.2
```

Running `pip install -r requirements.txt` yields

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow>=1.15.2 (from ethnicolr) (from versions: none) ERROR: No
> matching distribution found for tensorflow>=1.15.2

Running `pip list` shows, that Tensorflow was installed. But it's not called `tensorflow`, but `tensorflow-macos` or `tensorflow-metal`.

```
tensorboard             2.7.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.0
tensorflow-estimator    2.7.0
tensorflow-macos        2.7.0
tensorflow-metal        0.3.0
```

What is a solution here? There must be more packages out there with the requirement of Tensorflow...

Comment: I do not know if tensorflow officially support M1... Have you tried with a guide like [that](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2021/09/24/installing-tensorflow-in-macos-m1-chip/) ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried multiple ways. And I am able to install Tensorflow. The thing is that the dependency is called "tensorflow-macos", but ethicolr depends on "tensorflow" and this I think throws an error. I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: What return `which python` command?

Comment: It returns `/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/bin/python`. So to clarify: I am able to install TensorFlow, but not the M1 optimized version. Or, to be even more precise: I am also able to install the M1 optimized version, but other packages don't recognize that I have TensorFlow installed. My guess is because the package is called `tensorflow-macos`.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to run. I'm not sure if this is ideal but I'm sharing my solution to maybe help anyone running into the same issue. I installed tensorflow `2.6.0` in a virtual environment using conda / mambaforge. I opted for `2.6.0` because `2.5.2` is not available for M1 and `2.5.0` wasn't working. You can read about installing Mamaforge [here](https://coiled.io/blog/apple-arm64-mambaforge/). After that, I installed Tensorflow with

```
conda install tensorflow==2.6.0
```

I also set the pandas version to `pandas>1.2.3` in the `requirements.txt` of my own project (same as in ethnicolr). This resolved to pandas `1.3.3`.

Next, I had to solve the dependency issue with ethnicolr, since ethnicolr requires tensorflow `2.5.2`. I did that by forking the ethnicolr repo and creating a branch where I pin the tensorflow version to `2.6.0` in the `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`. You find this branch over [here](https://github.com/ospaarmann/ethnicolr/tree/apple_m1_support_tensorflow_2_6_0). To use this github branch, I changed the line in my `requirements.txt` to:

```
git+https://github.com/ospaarmann/ethnicolr.git@apple_m1_support_tensorflow_2_6_0#egg=ethnicolr
```

Now I had an issue with a dependency mismatch with numpy. It is described in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp). What happened was that importing pandas or ethnicolr would throw this error:

```
>>> from ethnicolr import census_ln, pred_census_ln, pred_wiki_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ethnicolr/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ethnicolr.census_ln import census_ln
  File "/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ethnicolr/census_ln.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
  File "/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
  File "/Users/olespaarmann/mambaforge/envs/diversity_scraper/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

The solution here is to just ignore the dependency issues and manually install a newer version of numpy. It doesn't work when I set the numpy version in my `requirements.txt` because this throws a dependency error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install numpy>=1.20.0 and tensorflow==2.6.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested numpy>=1.20.0
    tensorflow 2.6.0 depends on numpy~=1.19.2
```

So I just installed it with `python -m pip install numpy==1.20.0`. And now everything seems to work.