# ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

Tags: python, ta-lib

I am trying to install TA-LIB (library) in python to analyze financial data. I was able to download talib by following the talib installation instructions below, but when I run the following executable program, I get the following error and have not found a solution. What is the possible solution?

Environment: Mac OS Monterey
Python 3.9.0

Executable program: import talib

Error:
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

TA-LIB installation program:
brew install ta-lib
pip install ta-lib

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp)