# No module named pandas when running code using sudo (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi, sudo, python-module

I am trying to detect keystroke on my Raspberry Pi 4. To do that I am running the code as,

```
sudo python3 example.py
```

But I get error, "No module named Pandas" (The code uses Pandas). But When I am running the code using Thonny, I get no error. And also I have pandas installed (confirmed using "pip list"). So, apparently If I run the code as root I get "no modules named pandas". If I run the code as,

```
python3 example.py
```

then no problem with pandas, but python keyboard module throws an error because of root access required. I have checked,

```
which python
>>>/usr/bin/python
sudo which python
>>>/usr/bin/python
```

Then I compared between

```
pip3 list
sudo pip3 list
```

Surprisingly I found that pip3 list gives me pandas(1.4.1). But no pandas were found in sudo pip3 list!!! Now what i did was,

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

Now the error has changed to, "numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 40 from PyObject". But occurring only when running code as sudo.

Comment: Try reinstalling numpy. sudo pip3 install --upgrade numpy. This is based on:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66138833/2612429

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me that the packages installed for the superuser might be different than the packages installed for the base user -- this could happen if pandas was installed via `pip3 install --user pandas`. Alternatively, the user and sudo might be using different versions of python.

To start debugging, I'd compare the output of `sudo which python` and `which python` as well as `sudo pip3 list` and look for any differences in environment.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Based on your suggestions, I have updated the question. Will you kindly give a look. Thank you.