# (PyCharm) Pydicom ValueError

Tags: numpy, python-3.8, pydicom

Python3.8 in PyCharm

`pydicom==2.1.2`

`numpy==1.20.2`

When calling pydicom, I get this error: `ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject`

Tried upgrading/re-installing pydicom, re-installing numpy.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have current `pydicom`, `numpy` and `libjpeg-openjpeg` versions. Which versions are you using?

Comment: Explanation of what might have gone wrong in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66743692) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69528768) answer. Maybe it could help to reinstall the pylibjpeg-openjpeg package.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to `numpy==1.22.0` solved the problem.
[image]