# Numpy error when importing pandas: ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, raspberry-pi

I am getting this on a Raspberry Pi zero after having used it no problem for months, I just turned it on again after a few months and now I can't import pandas:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Oct 31 2022, 14:04:00) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 44 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
```

This error is very similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66060487/1609514), but slightly different.

I tried updating my system:

```bash
sudo apt update
```

And I tried uninstalling and re-installing numpy and pandas:

```bash
sudo apt remove python3-numpy python3-pandas
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy python3-pandas python3-scipy python3-sklearn python3-numexpr
```

but it does not fix it.

Any ideas?

**Version info**

```
python3-numpy/oldstable,now 1:1.16.2-1 armhf [installed]
python3-pandas-lib/oldstable,now 0.23.3+dfsg-3 armhf [installed,automatic]
python3-pandas/oldstable,now 0.23.3+dfsg-3 all [installed]
```

**System info**

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using pip or conda?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi doesn't have enough memory to build numpy.  They need to use an apt binary.

Comment: @jared I've tried miniconda on the RPi and pip and found apt-get worked best (everything was working fine when I last turned it on).  This is also recommended by [Geoff Boing](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/03/scientific-python-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: @Bill I recommend adding the library versions to your post. It may be relevant.

Comment: @jared I added the pandas and numpy versions.  I can show others if needed.

Comment: @TimRoberts Numpy is working fine.  It's just Pandas.

Comment: From your error, imported pandas is in `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py` - the apt-get one should be in `/usr/` somewhere.  This looks like a `pip --user` install.

Comment: Hi @RoryYorke. You might be right. `pip list` shows `pandas 1.3.5`. What do you think?  Should I uninstall that or the apt-get one?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [@Rory Yorke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008142/rory-yorke) for figuring out the problem in the comments.

> From your error, imported pandas is in `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py` - the apt-get one should be in `/usr/` somewhere. This looks like a `pip --user` install.

Clearly there were two version of Pandas installed. Removing the pip version solved the problem:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi:~/code $ pip uninstall pandas
Found existing installation: pandas 1.3.5
Uninstalling pandas-1.3.5:
  Would remove:
    /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-1.3.5.dist-info/*
    /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/*
Proceed (Y/n)? Y
  Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.3.5
pi@raspberrypi:~/code $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Oct 31 2022, 14:04:00) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
```