# RuntimeWarning('numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 16 from C header, got 96 from PyObject')

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

When importing some packages while `warnings.catch_warnings()` is active, I see the warning

`RuntimeWarning('numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 16 from C header, got 96 from PyObject')`

or

`RuntimeWarning('numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 216 from C header, got 232 from PyObject')`

These are warnings, not exceptions, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060487/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-exp), but I'm still wondering if I should be concerned about these warnings.

Also, I'm on Windows getting the packages mostly from conda-forge, so I'm not building them myself, and my installed numpy is > 1.20.0.

Does anyone know if I should be concerned about these warnings?

Comment: `When importing some packages` Which ones? Also, what versions of those packages are you using?