# PyAudio.write SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

When I was trying to play a wave file with PyAudio-0.2.11 in a python-3.10.1 virtualenv(created with python-3.9.0 venv and upgraded), I received an exception and nothing is played, others just go well.

```
Exception in thread WavPlayer:rsrc/sound.wav:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Code/py/tetris/tetris.py", line 39, in run
    self.play()
  File "/Code/py/tetris/tetris.py", line 35, in play
    self.stream.write(data)
  File "/Code/py/tetris/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 584, in write
    pa.write_stream(self._stream, frames, num_frames,
SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats
```

I do not know what `'#' format` stands for, and I am sure that my code has nothing to do with C API, but it run well under python-3.9.x, is that a problem with the PyAudio library itself? How can I solve that?

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately, a breaking change was introduced in Python 3.10 (see [bpo-40943](https://bugs.python.org/issue40943) and [PEP-0353](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/)), and thus PyAudio needs updated.

EDIT: This has been fixed upstream since PyAudio 0.2.12! Leaving the interim below for posterity, but a simple version bump is all that is needed now.

---

I've submitted a fix upstream, but as the project has not been updated since 2017, I'm not quite sure how quick it will get reviewed.

In the meantime, you are free to build [my fork](https://git.skeh.site/skeh/pyaudio) from source and use that :)

Comment: Nice work! your pyaudio version works with no problem.

Answer (score 6):

Necroposting.

As @skeh indicated, starting with *Python 3.10* some (backward compatible) functionality was disabled on purpose. That means that some extension modules will no longer work *OOTB*.
Check [[GitHub]: python/cpython - PEP 353: Drop support for PyArg_ParseTuple() "#" formats when PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN is not defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85115) for more details.

*PyAudio* (*v0.2.11*) is one such module.
Things are fixed in ***v0.2.12*** (which was released in the meantime).

*Python 3.**11*** *.whl*s were not published on [[PyPI]: PyAudio 0.2.12 - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/0.2.12/#files) at answer time (they were added afterwards).
I built and placed them at **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PyAudio/v0.2.12](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyAudio/v0.2.12)**.

Also forked the (original) *PyAudio* *repo* at: [[GitHub]: CristiFati/pyaudio - PyAudio](https://github.com/CristiFati/pyaudio)

Similar problem on another package: [[SO]: Can't install pyo using pip (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73512700/4788546).

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error as well.
Tried installing a variety of pymongo versions until resolved.
version 3.12 did it for me

`pip install --upgrade pymongo=3.12`

Comment: I also had this error while using Pymongo and it disappeared after installing pymongo==3.10.1

Comment: *PyMongo* has nothing to do with the question. This isn't an answer but a comment. -1.