# packages not found after installation on Windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, seaborn

I switched from a Mac to Windows 11 and have issues with my python scripts or with the packages more precisely. I installed seaborn with `pip install seaborn` via PowerShell but when I run `import seaborn` in Visual Studio Code I get "No module name seaborn". Similarly installed matplotlib and getting the error "No module named 'matplotlib.docstring'" when I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. Installed Python 3.10.6 instead of the newest version and now matplotlib is working, but this is not really a good longterm solution and also seaborn still isn't working. I verified that the interpreter is installed in the same location as everything else, also I installed WSL to use that instead of the PowerShell but nothing changes and I'm out of ideas as to what the issue could be. Does anyone have an idea what's going on here and how I can ensure a smooth installation without having issues with every single package?

Comment: Have you tried running `pip list`? What does it return?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57882963/4788546.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different instances of Python can be installed on your system in parallel. The version that VS Code uses may not be the same that you access in the terminal.

First, verify which version of Python is used in VS Code by checking the status bar at the bottom. You should find something like this:

[image: status bar of VS code displaying the Python version]

Now, click on the Python version number, which opens this interpreter selection:

[image: Python interpreter selection of VS code]

In gray, you see the path of the used Python. Finally, run the following in your PowerShell:

```
Get-Command python
```

If the output path does not correspond to the one shown in VS Code, you can either select the correct interpreter in VS Code (via the interpreter selection), or install the package in the correct Python environment by specifying the full path.

E.g., in my example, I could run:

```bash
/usr/bin/python -m pip install seaborn
```

This forces the package installation in the Python version that my VS Code uses.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try the cmd in VSC by opening a new terminal (Terminal -> New terminal) and then executing it. Sometimes, VSC doesn't find the pkgs installed on system.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35005745)

Comment: @SamMason I can’t see the problem here, could you be so kind and clarify the verdict?

Comment: answers on stackoverflow should aim to provide enough information to help other people who are in a similar situation and I'm not even sure this addresses the underlying issue.  Python packages can be installed in various places (e.g. system, user, virtual environment) under the Python version that installed them.  Equipping the user with the information to find out which is being used in different situations (i.e. PowerShell, WSL, editor) seems more useful in the long run.