# Rpy2 on windows

Tags: r, installation, package

I want to install rpy2 on my windows machine and it gives me the following famous error

```
      self.convert_pycparser_error(e, csource)
      File "c:\users\96171\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lxsxk7q4\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.14.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 336, in convert_pycparser_error
        raise CDefError(msg)
    cffi.CDefError: cannot parse "void __cffi_extern_python_start; void _capsule_finalizer(SEXP); void __cffi_extern_python_stop;"
    <cdef source string>:495:96: Illegal character '\r'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lxsxk7q4\rpy2\
```

I have done the following:

- upgraded set up tools
- upgraded pip to the latest version

I have followed the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915714/installing-rpy2-on-windows) for installing rpy2 on windows and they're saying we have to download a precompiled binary in order for this to work.

I have downloaded from the followinf [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2) this wheel: 
`rpy2‑2.9.5‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` however I am still facing trouble; I did as follows:

- After I downloaded `rpy2‑2.9.5‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`
- I opened cmd as Administrator in the directory where the wheel is downloaded
- I set `%R_USER%` in the system variables to my username as such: R_USER C:\Users\my_username
  However I am getting the following error:

`ERROR: rpy2-2.9.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

in the website for the [binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2) they say that:

> Rpy2 (discontinued, unstable): provide access to the R software environment for statistical computing and graphics. **Requires R 3.3**, and I have R 3.6.2 on  my system. Is this causing the error?

Comment: All downloaded wheels from the binaries site must conform to your machine (OS, 32/64-bit architecture, Python version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER**
The issue was that I downloaded the wrong wheel. `cp37` means `CPython 3.7` and I have `python 3.6` on my system. I downloaded `rpy2-2.9.5-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` istead of `rpy2-2.9.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` and it worked.

Also as I faced problems with `R_USER`and `R_HOME` I did the following in my python script:

```
import os
# see the following 2 lines
os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2'
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'C:/Users/96171/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/rpy2' #path depends on where you installed Python. Mine is the site packages of the regular python installation, it could have been Anaconda

# importing rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r = robjects.r
r['source']('sample_r.r')
```

References: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698877/how-to-setup-environment-variable-r-user-to-use-rpy2-in-python)

**UPDATED**
To avoid `os calls` I was able to achieve the desired behavior by including `R_USER` and `R_HOME` to the `SYSTEM VARIABLE` in  `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES`

- **R_USER**:
  C:\Users\96171\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\rpy2
- **R_HOME**: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2

Comment: If you have Admin rights, you can permanently set those environment variables and avoid `os` calls.