# Installing rpy2 in Windows 10 through Anaconda so that it uses already installed packages

Tags: python, r, windows, anaconda, rpy2

I want to use rpy2 through one of my Anaconda environments. I installed it by opening the terminal for that environment and running `conda install -c r rpy2` as per [these instructions](https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023857134-Setting-up-rpy2-on-Windows). I also ran `pip install rpy2` [just to make sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486081/install-and-use-rpy2-using-conda-so-that-it-uses-default-r-installation-in-us), but got back

```
Requirement already satisfied: rpy2 in c:\users\rcardoso\.conda\envs\smartwatt\lib\site-packages (2.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\rcardoso\.conda\envs\smartwatt\lib\site-packages (from rpy2) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\rcardoso\.conda\envs\smartwatt\lib\site-packages (from rpy2) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\rcardoso\.conda\envs\smartwatt\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->rpy2) (1.1.1)
```

I want rpy2 to use my current R installation, which was not done through Anaconda and already has a number of packages installed. I tried to follow the instructions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225506/rpy2-on-windows) for setting up the system variables. The relevant system variables ended up looking like this:

[image: System variables]

However, when I run

```
for row in rpy2.situation.iter_info():
    print(row)
```

in my Spyder iPython console, as per [rpy2 documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/introduction.html#getting-started), it seems it's not picking up the R_HOME and R_USER environment variables, as it's returning:

```
Python version:
3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 23 2020, 22:22:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Looking for R's HOME:
    Environment variable R_HOME: None
    Calling `R RHOME`: C:\Users\rcardoso\.conda\envs\Smartwatt\lib\R
    InstallPath in the registry: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3
R version:
    In the PATH: 
    Used to build rpy2: 3-6.0--76424
Additional directories to load R packages from:
None
```

What should I do so that I am able to use my current R installation (not the one which was apparently installed along with rpy2) and packages? I haven't been able to find consistent information on how to correctly install rpy2 in Windows 10 through Anaconda for my specific situation.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: @AMC assuming you're referring to the packages installed in the environment, you can find them here: https://pastebin.com/SbaBbZDM

Answer (score 0):

It seems anaconda is not using your defined system variables.

From the post you have mentioned ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225506/rpy2-on-windows)), have you try setting the environments directly at your script?

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = r"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3"
os.environ['R_USER'] = r"C:\Users\rcardoso\.conda\envs\Smartwatt\Lib\site-packages\rpy2"
```

There is another solution you can try: defining environment variables directly in the conda environment. Check first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598963/how-to-set-specific-environment-variables-when-activating-conda-environment).