# pygraphviz 1.5 default edge no arrow?

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have updated to pygraphviz 1.5 using this wheel here [Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6/54890705#54890705).

I'm having problems with it.

```
import pygraphviz as pgv

G = pgv.AGraph()

G.add_node('a')
G.add_node('b')
G.add_edge('a', 'b')
g_string = G.string()

print(g_string)
```

gives me

```
strict digraph {
    a -- b;
}
```

while the same code ran on previous version 1.3 gives me

```
strict digraph {
    a -> b;
}
```

I have even tried

`G.add_edge('a', 'b', arrowhead="normal")` which gives `a -- b [arrowhead=normal];` but draws with no arrowheads.

I'm running `graphviz 2.38`.
`pygraphviz 1.3` on python 2.7.
`pygraphviz 1.5` on python 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start by pointing out that in order for this example to work, **it's not enough** to have the *PyGraphviz* module installed (check [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6/54890705#54890705)), but a version of *Graphviz* is required as well, as *PyGraphviz* uses one of its tools (called ***nop***). 
It is available for download, anyway I chose to build it (for *32bit*, but that's not relevant).

Also, I tested with 2 *.whl*s:

- One (that I've) built for *Python **3.6** (64 bit)*
- One built for *Python **2.7** (64 bit)*

Since there was the possibility of me having to modify them (for debugging purposes), I didn't `pip install` them, but rather unpacked them in *cwd* (which required some extra code):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055196206]> dir /b
> code00.py
> pygraphviz131_27
> pygraphviz15_36
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055196206]> tree /a
> Folder PATH listing for volume Work
> Volume serial number is 3655-6FED
> E:.
> +---pygraphviz131_27
> |   \---pygraphviz
> |       \---tests
> \---pygraphviz15_36
>     \---pygraphviz
>         \---tests
> ```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


# @TODO - cfati: The 5 lines below are because I unpacked the 2 `.whl`s in the current dir, instead of `pip install`ing them
maj, min = sys.version_info[:2]
if maj == 3 and min == 6:
    sys.path.insert(0, "pygraphviz15_36")
elif maj == 2 and min == 7:
    sys.path.insert(0, "pygraphviz131_27")
# @TODO end

import pygraphviz as pgv


def main():
    print(pgv)
    g = pgv.AGraph(directed=len(sys.argv) > 1)
    g.add_node("a")
    g.add_node("b")
    g.add_edge("a", "b")
    #print(dir(g))
    g_string = g.string()  # Nice var name, btw :)
    print(g_string)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055196206]> set PATH=%PATH%;e:\Work\Dev\Fati\WinBuild\graphviz\src\graphviz\Release\Graphviz\bin
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055196206]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_02.07.15_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> <module 'pygraphviz' from 'pygraphviz131_27\pygraphviz\__init__.pyc'>
> strict digraph {
>         a -> b;
> }
>
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055196206]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> <module 'pygraphviz' from 'pygraphviz15_36\\pygraphviz\\__init__.py'>
> strict graph "" {
>         a -- b;
> }
> ```

As seen, the problem is easily reproducible. Now, the outputs ***--*** *vs.* ***->*** look **awfully a lot to how I'd represent an undirected *vs.* directed graph edge**. I looked in the source code and found something strange.

[[GitHub.PyGraphviz 1.5]: class **AGraph**(*thing=None, filename=None, data=None, string=None, handle=None, name='', strict=True, directed=False, **attr*)](http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.5/reference/agraph.html#pygraphviz.AGraph) has the `directed=False` arg. Setting it to *True*, fixed the problem.

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055196206]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_02.07.15_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dummy_arg
> Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> <module 'pygraphviz' from 'pygraphviz131_27\pygraphviz\__init__.pyc'>
> strict digraph {
>         a -> b;
> }
>
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055196206]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dummy_arg
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> <module 'pygraphviz' from 'pygraphviz15_36\\pygraphviz\\__init__.py'>
> strict digraph "" {
>         a -> b;
> }
> ```

I said that I discovered something strange: well, for *PyGraphviz 1.3.1* **things are the same**: **`directed=False`** (code **and** doc), yet it somehow initializes the graph **as it would be directed**. 
A quick check on *agraph.py* (on the 2 package versions) didn't reveal where this difference comes from, so I can safely assume that it's because of *Graphviz* package versions that the 2 *PyGraphviz* versions were built with.

Nevertheless, ***PyGraphviz 1.5* (built by me) behavior is the correct one**.

Comment: You're welcome! I've learned smth about *PyGraphviz*. I will have to update the other question, to include the fact that some (I guess most of) scenarios will also require *Graphviz*. Also, I changed the *GitHub* repository name, currently editing other question, when done will contain up to date info.

Answer (score 2):

As documents [state](http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.5/reference/agraph.html#pygraphviz.AGraph), by default AGraph is undirected. You'll have to specify `directed=True` attribute during the graph construction:

```py
>>> G = pgv.AGraph(directed=True)
>>> G.add_node('a')
>>> G.add_node('b')
>>> G.add_edge('a', 'b')
>>> g_string = G.string()
>>>
>>> print(g_string)
strict digraph "" {
    a -> b;
}
```