# Installing Pygraphviz on Windows 10 64bits, python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygraphviz

I'm trying to install PyGraphViz on my Windows 10 64bits machine.
I first tried with `pip install pygraphviz`, and got an `can't find graphviz\cgraph.h` error (I have Graphviz 2.38 installed).
Then after specifying the path to graphviz `include` folder aswell as the path to `lib\release\lib', I got a bunch of`unresolved external symbols` :

[pip output](https://pastebin.com/F1UfEj2J)

I couldn't find an answer on PyGraphviz github issues although some people are complaining about the same error. How can I get pygraphviz to build and install ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6/54890705#54890705

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6)