# conda-forge PackagesNotFoundError for pygraphviz

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pygraphviz

I am trying to install `pygraphviz` but conda is not finding it in the channels. Below is the error I get. `Conda-forge` is already in the channel list and I tried with `-c conda-forge` but still does not work. I also tried `bioconda` channel and did not work.

```
> conda install -c anaconda pygraphviz
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pygraphviz

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

`Pygraphviz` should be there in [bioconda](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/pygraphviz) and [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pygraphviz) according to the documentation, but I still cannot find the package. 
I also update conda `conda update conda`, and still no luck.

Is there something wrong here? or something I am missing?

Comment: In the conda repositories pygraphviz is only available for linux and osx, but not for windows.

Comment: :( that is just sad! And now i saw that osx and linux tag in conda documentation. Thanks a lot for pointing it out for me.

Comment: Just as a side note, you should prefer to just leave out the `-c anaconda`, it is just a mirror of the default channels

Comment: I'm voting to close this, since the Conda package simply isn't available on Windows, and that information is present on the [package's page on Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pygraphviz).

Answer (score 1):

You are installing it from the wrong channel. Do:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pygraphviz
```

Updates: Windows

It appears that there are challenges installing pygraphviz on windows. Assuming that graphiz is installe and added to Path, which is a separate program (not python library) these solution might work

```sh
# Tom Hanks’ answer 
conda install graphviz pygraphviz -c alubbock
```

See SO answers [Installing Pygraphviz on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6)

Comment: i tried several channels, like `conda-forge` and `bioconda`. the problem seems that it is not available in windows

Comment: The issue is OS. It appears that the available package are for unix. Let me see what other options you have

Comment: Updated my response

Comment: It's alright `conda install -c conda-forge pygraphviz` works on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

"conda install graphviz pygraphviz -c alubbock" worked for me, within an Anaconda cme.exe terminal (and several failed attempts with other approaches). Elsewhere I had also been told to install a C+ compiler, which I did within Visual Studio. But maybe you can try without installing the C+ compiler

Comment: If you're working in conda, the C compiler comes pre-installed with it. That's the beauty of working with conda, it makes life so much easier installing Python packages.