# ImportError Pyo

Tags: python, importerror, pyo

I'm trying to import pyo in python3.8.8 and I'm not getting any results. When I try to run the command:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
import pyo
File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyo_*init*_.py", line 28, in 
from .lib import analysis as analysis
File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyo\lib\analysis.py", line 32, in 
from ._core import *
File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyo\lib_core.py", line 58, in 
from .._pyo import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pyo: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.**

How can I solve this?

Comment: I see you’re running this on Windows.  I’ve read that PYO has issues with some OS’s.  I’ve noticed that some people have tried running this on a Linux VM and had better luck.

Comment: Check out this link for some info from the developer. http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/compiling.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on windows. What version of pyo do you have installed? I saw that it was only version 1.0.1 that python 3.8 support was introduced. Try uninstalling pyo, then make sure you install the newest version. Also, did you install with pip? If you did, try installing from their downloadable releases on github. What code did you write that caused this error? I need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using *pc032* (*032bit*) *Python*. Last *PyO* version with *pc032* (on *Win*) support is [[PyPI]: pyo 1.0.1](https://pypi.org/project/pyo/1.0.1) (from *191127*). But I didn't see the *Python 3.8* *.whl* among files (neither for a couple of older versions).

Just out of curiosity: how did you install *PyO*?

In order to get things going either:

- Switch to *pc064* (*064bit*) *Python*
- Use a (*pc032*) *Python* version that prebuilt *.whl* exists for
- I've built *v1.0.4* (latest at answer time) and placed the *.whl*s at [[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PyO/v1.0.4](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyO/v1.0.4). Download and install the preferred one (check [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890705/4788546) (at the end) for more details about the process)