# How to fix error during pythonnet installation

Tags: python, pip, python.net

When I try to use following command:

```
pip install pythonnet
```

I see error that you can see below:

```
Collecting pythonnet
  Using cached pythonnet-2.5.2.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\d4wt0\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pythonnet) (2.20)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pythonnet, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pythonnet
    Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\d4wt0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\d4wt0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jlv07504\\pythonnet_0928bad80975481c9950abc5017a28b4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\d4wt0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jlv07504\\pythonnet_0928bad80975481c9950abc5017a28b4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\d4wt0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x2n0fvt3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\d4wt0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\pythonnet'
         cwd: C:\Users\d4wt0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jlv07504\pythonnet_0928bad80975481c9950abc5017a28b4\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\d4wt0\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\d4wt0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jlv07504\\pythonnet_0928bad80975481c9950abc5017a28b4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\d4wt0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jlv07504\\pythonnet_0928bad80975481c9950abc5017a28b4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\d4wt0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-x2n0fvt3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\d4wt0\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\pythonnet' Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I fix it? I tried to install that package using PyCharm, but there is the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey can you mention your `python` version please!!

Comment: Sure, it's 3.9.

Comment: pip install pythonnet==3.0.0a2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [Python.NET docs](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) I can see it doesn't support `python 3.9`. You can download wheel file from
[here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonnet).

As your `python` version is 3.9, download `pythonnet‑2.5.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl` (for 32-bit `python` version) or `pythonnet‑2.5.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl` (for 64-bit `python` version).

Then specify a full path to wheel file for installation.

Example:

```sh
pip install C:\Users\User\Downloads\pythonnet‑2.5.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Please see @Stephen Simmons's answer which is better for 3.9

Answer (score 16):

The current pre-release version supports Python 3.9. It can be installed with `pip` using:

```sh
pip install --pre pythonnet
```

(This answer came from https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1262.)

Answer (score 2):

Split this out of [[SO]: pywebview installing Error Python windows 10 (Python 3.10.5) "pip install pywebview" (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73797850/4788546).

You're using *Python 3.**9***.
According to [[PyPI]: pythonnet - Release history](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/#history), latest released version (at answer time) is ***v2.5.2***. Unfortunately, highest *Python* version that the *.whl*s are built for is ***v3.8***. Since there is no *.whl* for your version, it tries to build it from source, and that's where it fails.

To get past this, you could either:

1. **Use an older *Python* version** (*v3.8*) that has all the packages built for it. Everything should work *OOTB*.
   The drawback is obvious, older versions are only receiving security updates and will go out of support sooner, and some packages (newer versions) might no longer support them.
2. **Install / build it manually** (`python -m pip install pythonnet`)

   1. Install *v3.0.0**rc6*** (***!!! PRE RELEASE !!!***) available at original answer time (**check the end of this section**). Pass ***--pre*** flag to *PIP*, as instructed in [[GitHub]: pythonnet/pythonnet - Troubleshooting on Windows, Linux, and OSX](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows,-Linux,-and-OSX):

      > `pip install pythonnet [--pre] -U` (--pre gets the latest development build uploaded to PyPI)

      So, the command line should be: `python -m pip install --pre pythonnet`.
      Or specify the version directly: `pip install pythonnet==3.0.0rc6`.

      **On *220929*, *PythonNET 3.0.0* was released!**.
      You can use that one from now on. It's one *.whl* only (doesn't seem to be tied to *Python* versions).
   2. Find a 3<sup>rd</sup>-party repository that has prebuilt *.whl*s for newer *Python* versions:

      - **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PythonNET/v2.5.2](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PythonNET/v2.5.2)** (see below)
      - [[UCI.LFD]: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages - PythonNET, provide integration with the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) and an application scripting tool for .NET.](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonnet)
   3. Build *v2.5.2*. But the process is shitty (it has been much improved in *v3*), as it requires lots of stuff:

      - *MSBuild* - installed by *VStudio* (but I think it can also be installed standalone)
      - *CLang* - can be installed standalone, but also by other software like:

        - *Android Studio*
        - *Nix* emulators (*MinGW*, *MSYS2*, *Cygwin*, ...)
      - Some environment variables being set
      - A file needs to be patched

      I did all of the above (and published the binaries in the *GitHub* *URL* mentioned in the answer).

---

#### Update *#0*

Built *.whl*s and published them on [[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PythonNET/v2.5.2](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PythonNET/v2.5.2) (*win_amd64* and *win32* for *Python*: *v3.11*, *v3.10*, *v3.9*). Check [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890705/4788546) (*Shortcut* section - at the end) details regarding custom *.whl* installation.
The only test I did is `import clr` (successful - no crash or error) in the interpreter console.