# Python.Runtime.PythonException: since Python.NET 3.0 int can not be converted to Enum implicitly. Use Enum(int_value)

Tags: python, enums, python.net, osisoft

I recently moved my code to a new computer at work. A basic example code is as follows (but you wouldn't be able to run it as you can't connect to my server - sorry that I couldn't make it any more reproducible).

With the new computer, I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: since Python.NET 3.0 int can not be converted to Enum implicitly. Use Enum(int_value) in method OSIsoft.AF.Asset.AFValue RecordedValue(OSIsoft.AF.Time.AFTime, OSIsoft.AF.Data.AFRetrievalMode) ---> Python.Runtime.PythonException: since Python.NET 3.0 int can not be converted to Enum implicitly. Use Enum(int_value)*".

My old computer uses Spyder 4 and Python 3.7 and Python.NET 2.5.2. The new computer uses Spyder 5 and Python 3.9 and Python.NET 3.0. Because of IT restrictions, I am unable to install the same version of Spyder and Python on my computer. However, I do not think it is causing this error.

Would anyone have any idea what would cause an **Enum**-related problem? Thanks!

```
import PIconnect as PI

def pidownload(tag):
    with PI.PIServer() as server:
        point = server.search(tag)[0]
        data = point.recorded_value('-1m')
        data=data.to_frame()
    return data
tag='xxxx.pv' #confidential data tag replaced with xxxx
print(pidownload(tag))
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: Which version of .NET was on the old machine?

Comment: Hi Ethan, old machine is pythonnet 2.5.2. Edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the documentation for the `RecordedValue` function in [OSIsoft's documentation](https://docs.osisoft.com/bundle/af-sdk/page/html/M_OSIsoft_AF_PI_PIPoint_RecordedValue.htm) and the documentation for `recorded_value` in the [PIConnect documentation](https://piconnect.readthedocs.io/en/develop/api/PI/PIconnect.PI.html?highlight=PIServer#PIconnect.PI.PIPoint), it seems that the Python-side function is sending an enum and the C#-side function is receiving an enum value. However, when inspecting the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/Hugovdberg/PIconnect/blob/b614494bcd2110e659ca44716dd3b905271c3bb6/PIconnect/PIData.py#L89) for PIConnect, we can see that the issue is with the `retrieval_mode` variable, which has a default value of `RetrievalMode.AUTO`, which is an `IntEnum`. It appears that the conversion is not working properly, as I noticed this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Hugovdberg/PIconnect/issues/630) on their repository.

**EDIT**

After further inspection, it looks like your issue is an installation problem and can be fixed by reinstalling `piconnect`, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67418533/how-to-fix-error-during-pythonnet-installation).

Answer (score 1):

It worked after downgrading to Python 3.8 (from 3.9) and to Python.NET 2.5 (from Python.NET 3.0). I think it simply doesn't work for python 3.9 onwards: http://pythonnet.github.io/.

Comment: Ok got it, I see that you’ve edited and removed “thank you” from my response. I don’t see a need to remove a friendly word from anyone’s response - the world could and should be a kinder place. 
And I’ve already accepted the answer beforehand.