# pywin32 not installed correctly and python script failed execution

Tags: python, pywin32

I have a python script which is refused to run:

```
py C:\Users\tester\move.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tester\Desktop\moveMousePeriodicallyAdmin2.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api, win32con
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I saw couple of solutions from various old thread however none of them fix the issue.

1. `pip show pywin32`
   no result is returned at terminal
2. `Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install`

and result is not good:

```
c:\Programme\Python35\Scripts>pywin32_postinstall.py -install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programme\Python35\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 613, in <module>
    install()
  File "C:\Programme\Python35\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 321, in install
    LoadSystemModule(lib_dir, "pywintypes")
  File "C:\Programme\Python35\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 159, in LoadSystemModule
    mod = imp.load_dynamic(modname, filename)
  File "C:\Programme\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: What's your *PyWin32* version? How did you install it? Try uninstall / install: `"C:\Programme\Python35\python.exe" -m pip uninstall pywin32` then `"C:\Programme\Python35\python.exe" -m pip install pywin32`.

Comment: not sure if this is network issue, I can surf internet. however install not proceed. 
c:\Programme\Python35\Scripts>"C:\Programme\Python35\python.exe" -m pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002205EFCE4E0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pywin32/

Comment: Try downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/ce/598fa78c2f475dfd7d24fc66e608ab2579d03a696ed6d1a3cb2cb96ad4b7/pywin32-301-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl, and install it locally. Check [\[SO\]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890705/4788546) (*Shortcut* section at the end) for details regarding custom *.whl* installation.

Comment: @CristiFati pywin32-301-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: I did this and the component installed, but what is this component for? is it replace the pywin32? "C:\Programme\Python35\python.exe" -m pip install C:\Users\tester\Downloads\pygraphviz-1.5-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\8aso_build\downloads\pygraphviz-1.5-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
Successfully installed pygraphviz-1.5

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't provide enough details. *PyGrapviz* is not required at all in this case, it has nothing to do here, but I was giving it as an example, to do the same for *PyWin32*. So the *.whl* that I indicated does not work, let's try the *064bit* version:  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/77/b02f15f1a488c015f9d41dda1c83d97af8dc9c98f8dab5d4894fd01c4ee4/pywin32-300-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl.

Comment: @CristiFati it is same still. Not supported.

Comment: What *Python* do you have? How did you install it? `"C:\Programme\Python35\python.exe" -c "import sys;print(sys.version_info, sys.platform, sys.maxsize)"` What's the command that you used, when installing the 2 *.whl*s that failed?

Comment: i resolved the network issue, "C:\Programme\Python35\python.exe" -m pip install pywin32 installed properly then, pywin32_postinstall.py -install also success. issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the network issue, `"C:\Programme\Python35\python.exe" -m pip install pywin32` installed properly

Then `pywin32_postinstall.py -install` also success. issue resolved.